# Para que serve uma MySQL Transaction?

Tags: php, mysql, transações

Estava estudando alguns exemplos do MySQL com PHP e me deparei como seguinte trecho de código:

```php
try {
    $db->beginTransaction();

    $db->query('query 1');
    $db->query('query 2');
    $db->query('query 3');

    $db->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $db->rollback();
}
```

Pelo que pude perceber ao pesquisar os métodos, chama-se `Transaction`, mas eu não consegui entender porque isto é utilizado. Gostaria de saber como funciona, e alguns exemplos de situações reais em que isto poderia ser útil.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

## TL;DR

Bancos de dados SQL em geral, não somente o MySQL, são [transacionais](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_em_base_de_dados), isto é, eles permitem você executar uma sequência de operações como um bloco indivisível de forma a garantir a integridade dos dados em um ambiente com acesso concorrente.

## O Problema

No exemplo citado na pergunta, imagine que as queries #1, #2 e #3 são operações que afetam a base de dados e não usamos uma transação para controlá-las. Vamos usar como exemplo um e-commerce:

1. Atualiza dados de entrega do cliente
2. Insere um novo registro da compra efetuada, verificando se possui estoque
3. Debita o estoque dos produtos

Agora imagine dois clientes tentando finalizar suas compras neste e-commerce fictício. O servidor recebe duas requisições quase simultaneamente e começa a processar os pedidos na sequência apresentada acima. Os dois pedidos estão sendo processados simultaneamente em threads diferentes.

Imagine ainda que tanto o cliente A quanto o cliente B selecionaram um produto que tem apenas uma unidade em estoque. Podemos acabar com a seguinte linha de execução:

1. Thread A atualiza dados do cliente A (passo #1), verifica o estoque insere o registro da compra (passo #2)
2. A thread A é bloqueada e B passa a ser executada
3. Thread B atualiza dados do cliente B (passo #1), verifica o estoque insere o registro da compra (passo #2)
4. Thread B atualiza o estoque, que agora fica zerado
5. A thread B é bloqueada e A passa a ser executada
6. Thread A atualiza o estoque, que agora fica negativo!

Note que apesar do código verificar o estoque a ordem de execução faz com que a verificação não seja garantida no passo seguinte.

## A Solução

Bancos de dados transacionais usam o conceito [ACID](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID):

- **Atomicidade**: uma transação é uma sequência de operações indivisível, ou é executado como um todo, ou tudo é desfeito.
- **Consistência**: ao final da transação, o estado dos dados deve ser consistente.
- **Isolamento**: embora alguns sistemas permitam quebrar o isolamento, em geral, uma transação em andamento não pode ser acessada por outras transações de modo a evitar leitura de um estado inconsistente, uma "sujeira".
- **Durabilidade**: em caso de sucesso (*commit*) a persistência dos dados deve ser garantida

Para garantir esses conceitos, em geral, os bancos de dados usam bloqueios quando ocorrem acessos simultâneos à mesma estrutura de dados. Ou seja, se alguém já está mexendo nos dados, os demais tem que esperar ele acabar e aguardar sua vez na fila.

## Na prática

Ao usar bancos de dados transacionais, nós podemos usufruir deste controle de gerenciamento por parte dos SGBDRs (Sistemas Gerenciadores de Bancos de Dados Relacionais).

Incluindo o conceito de transação ACID no exemplo anterior, vamos ver como fica a execução:

1. Thread A inicia uma transação, atualiza dados do cliente A (passo #1), verifica o estoque insere o registro da compra (passo #2)
2. A thread A é bloqueada e B passa a ser executada
3. Thread B inicia uma transação, mas ao tentar atualizar os dados do cliente B ela é bloqueada porque a transação de A ainda não acabou
4. Thread A atualiza o estoque, que agora fica zerado, e faz *commit* na transação.
5. A thread B é desbloqueada e passa a ser executada
6. A thread B atualiza dados do cliente B (passo #1), verifica o estoque e retorna um erro pois não encontra o produto disponível
7. Thread B executa um *rollback* para desfazer as alterações que já havia efetuado

O resultado final é como se somente a thread A tivesse executado e B nunca existisse.

## Nem tudo é um mar de rosas

Existem alguns problemas inerentes às transações ACID, sendo o **desempenho** o maior deles.

Embora seja importante garantir a integridade dos dados, para muitos sistemas onde a disponibilidade é o fator mais crítico, um modelo que bloqueia acessos simultâneos torna-se inviável.

Este é um dos principais fatores para o surgimento e a adoção de diversos sistemas de bancos de dados não transacionais e [NoSQL](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL).

O importante é entender que o uso de transações tem um custo e em algumas ocasiões este pode ser alto demais. Uma das representações mais comuns do *trade-off* de persistência de dados é a seguinte (retirada [deste artigo](http://berb.github.io/diploma-thesis/community/061_challenge.html)):

[image: Trade-off entre propriedades de bancos de dados]

O gráfico demonstra que consistência, disponibilidade e particionamento (escalar o banco de dados em diversos nós) são recursos que afetam uns aos outros. Você simplesmente não pode ter o melhor dos três, segundo o [teorema de CAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem).

Bancos de dados relacionais geralmente sacrificam o particionamento em prol da consistência e da disponibilidade, enquanto *alguns* sistemas NoSQL sacrificam a consistência dos dados.

Answer (score 14):

[Transações](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_em_base_de_dados) garantem **atomicidade** a um conjunto de operações, ou seja, ou todas elas terão sucesso, ou todas elas falharão. Um exemplo clássico é o de uma transferência bancária, onde duas alterações são necessárias nos seus registros: 1) reduzir o saldo da conta A em X; 2) aumentar o saldo da conta B em X. Se a primeira operação for executada, e logo em seguida o sistema apresentar uma falha, o seu banco de dados ficará inconsistente: há X a menos na conta A, mas a conta B continua com o mesmo saldo. Inverter as operações não ajuda muito, pois pode ocorrer o caso inverso.

No seu exemplo, o SGBD garante que - no seu armazenamento persistente - ou todas as `query 1`, `query 2` e `query 3` completarão com sucesso (`commit`), ou o banco permanecerá no mesmo estado que se encontrava antes da `query 1` começar (`rollback`). Note que um `rollback` explícito não é necessário para que essa garantia seja cumprida - se o sistema falhar antes do `commit`, quando o mesmo for reiniciado o SGBD se encarregará de desfazer as ações parciais. Do mesmo modo, se o sistema falhar logo **após** o `commit` - antes que a persistência do restante dos dados esteja assegurada - o SGBD após a reinicialização se encarregará de completar as ações parciais, tal como registradas no seu diário (*journal*).

Outro benefício das transações, como apontado por @hernandes, é promover o **isolamento** do acesso por processos concorrentes. Se um processo iniciou uma sequência de *queries*, e outro processo quer acessar o banco, não seria correto que ele o acessasse no estado [provisório] no qual o primeiro processo o deixou. Não só o banco estaria [potencialmente] inconsistente, mas não há garantia alguma que aquelas alterações serão efetuadas de fato (pois o primeiro processo pode dar `rollback`). Ainda, alterações pelo processo 2 poderiam afetar as operações do processo 1.

Existem vários níveis de isolamento, que dependem do SGBD e de outros fatores:

- `read uncommited` - uma transação pode ler as escritas de outra antes do `commit`;
- `read commited` - uma transação só pode ler dados que já passaram pelo `commit`. Entretanto, duas ou mais leituras sucessivas [iguais] podem retornar dados diferentes (se outras transações acontecerem durante o curso da primeira);
- `repeatable read` - além da característica anterior, garante-se que toda linha lida uma vez durante o curso da transação permaneça igual durante leituras subsequentes. Ainda assim, é possível que uma mesma *query* retorne um número diferente de linhas e/ou linhas diferentes (se a transação concorrente acrescentou uma linha nova, por exemplo);

  - Nota: esse é o nível padrão do InnoDB no MySQL.
- `serializable` - o fenômeno acima não ocorre, toda leitura igual terá um resultado igual (alternativamente: o sistema não permitirá um `commit` se houver colisão entre duas transações concorrentes).

Comment: Excelente! dá uma visão mais acadêmica sobre o assunto, postei de forma mais prática, mas sua resposta também é muito válida!

Comment: @mgibsonbr "Note que um rollback explícito não é necessário para que essa garantia seja cumprida - se o sistema falhar antes do commit, quando o mesmo for reiniciado o SGBD se encarregará de desfazer as ações parciais."
Não é mesmo necessário? O mysql trata de fazer a reversão se alguma coisa falhar?

Comment: @JorgeB. Me refiro a uma falha "catastrófica" como por exemplo acabar a energia e a máquina desligar. Nesse caso, ao reiniciar o banco irá sim fazer a reversão automaticamente. Mas no curso normal do programa, é boa prática colocar um rollback explícito (mesmo para evitar "lixo" nos logs do BD).

Comment: @mgibsonbr Se tivermos 2 transações a ser tratadas ao mesmo tempo, na primeira estamos a escrever na tabela x, na segunda se tentarmos escrever na tabela x ao mesmo tempo, o que acontece?

Comment: @JorgeB. Esse é um assunto *bastante* complexo, seria melhor abrir uma nova pergunta para isso. Pessoalmente, não sei o que acontece, mas suspeito que ambas as escritas vão ser bem-sucedidas, somente a **ordem** das mesmas é indefinida (i.e. uma pode sobrescrever os dados da outra, se mexerem na mesma linha).

Answer (score 13):

o MySQL quando utilizando algum plugin de armazenamento mais recetente (InnoDB, XtraDB) tem suporte a `transações`, basicamente, commit e rollback, mas para que servem?

Ao iniciar uma transação, você basicamente diz ao mysql para marcar o estado atual do banco de dados, após fazer algumas queries que alteram a base (UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE) os resultados estão apenas disponíveis na sua sessão, e não foram persistidos no banco ainda, ao usar o comando commit é que você estará persistindo as mudanças, se algo der errado no meio do caminho, você pode fazer um rollback e deixar o banco exatamente como estava quando iniciou.

#### Exemplo:

```sql
SELECT * FROM EXEMPLO;
------
id    nome
1     Foo

START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO EXEMPLO (id, nome) VALUES (2, 'Bar');

# resultado da select para sua sessão:
SELECT * FROM EXEMPLO;
------
id    nome
1     Foo  
2     Bar

# resultado da select para outras sessões
SELECT * FROM EXEMPLO;
------
id    nome
1     Foo  

# Persistindo, caso Commit

COMMIT;

# resultado geral
SELECT * FROM EXEMPLO;
------
id    nome
1     Foo
2     Bar

# Caso Rollback

ROLLBACK;

# resultado geral
SELECT * FROM EXEMPLO;
------
id    nome
1     Foo
```

Comment: Só reforçando, o controle de transação serve bem também para o caso de vários INSERTS seguidos que dependem um do outro entre si. Por exemplo, uma Classe que quando for persistida vai criar registro em outras tabelas. Se no meio do processo, um INSERT falhar, o programador pode chamar o rollback e desfazer tudo, todos os dados antes "inseridos" não existiram.

Answer (score 4):

Transação (`Transaction`) em `MYSQL` nada mais é que um controle de execução, ou seja, se for satisfeitas as solicitações, a mesma é aceita, senão o banco de dados desfaz todas alterações associadas à aquela solicitação.

Desta forma efetua a confirmação (`Commit`) e mantem a ações caso seja executado de forma devida, mas caso ocorra um erro, o mesmo desfaz a ação (`Rollback`).

Um `Rollback` pode ser gerado por uma entrada inválida, erro interno no servidor, travamento, reinicialização, desligamento do mesmo durante a transação. A mesma pode ser definida dentro de uma procedure do `MYSQL`, desta forma sendo mais seguro, pois a comunicação do commit e/ou do rollback será feita diretamente no banco de dados e não por meio de um conector do banco em outra linguagem. Colocar o commit dentro de uma procedure com o devido controle de transação, evita entradas duplicadas se validado de forma correta.

Bancos, financeiras e afins utilizam este conceito para garantir a integridade da informação. Quando se faz um controle de transação precisamos dimensionar quais dados podem se perder caso ocorra um `Rollback`, existem dados que após cadastrados com uma consulta (`Select`) podem ser validados e reutilizados, desta forma reduzindo o procedimento em uma nova tentativa de inserção destas informações. Desta forma seriam executados `Commit` e `Rollback` para cada um destes itens e sempre revalidando as informações.

**Referência básica** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html

Sempre utilize InnoDB, caso seja outro tipo pode altera-lo da forma abaixo

```
ALTER TABLE clientes TYPE = InnoDB;
ALTER TABLE clientes ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Para fazer o commit e o rollback dentro da procedure, defina após o begin

```
BEGIN

DECLARE exit handler for sqlexception
  BEGIN
  ROLLBACK;
END;

DECLARE exit handler for sqlwarning
 BEGIN
 ROLLBACK;
END;

START TRANSACTION;

[Seu codigo MYSQL]

COMMIT;

END
```

Desta forma sua transação será 100% controlada pela base e mais segura.

Answer (score 4):

Uma transaction server para garantir que um conjunto de querys seja executado.

Imagine uma transação entre contas correntes, tirar dinheiro de uma conta e depositar na outra, Você vai ter que:

Subtrair o valor da conta A e Adicionar na Conta B

Se no momento que você subtrair o valor da conta A o servidor parar, você irá ter retirado o valor de A, mas não haverá adicionado esse valor na conta B

A transaction serve justamente para evitar isso, ela só vai completar a operação se tudo que for solicitado dentro da transaction for realizado com sucesso.