# MySQL Transaction Quando? Como? Porque?

Tags: php, mysql, transações

Estive a ler a pergunta [Para que serve uma MySQL Transaction?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1924/7210) e fiquei com muitas dúvidas sobre este assunto.

**Quando devemos usar transações?

 Porque devemos usar transações?

 Como devemos usar transações?**

Alguns exemplos:

- No caso de eu estar num [site de vendas de produtos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1940/7210), em PHP e que tenha *stocks*, e que os mesmos não possam baixar de zero o que acontece ou o que posso fazer se: 
  O *stock* de um produto está com uma unidade e temos dois clientes a tentar comprar o produto. Começa a transação num deles, o outro consegue ter acesso a BD? Ou a *query* SQL lança uma exceção no segundo cliente a tentar comprar o produto?
  **Não causara muito embaraço se estiverem muitos clientes a tentarem comprar o mesmo produto com *stock* igual a um?**
- No caso de se estarem a registar vários utilizadores ao mesmo tempo faz sentido cada um deles ter uma nova transação? Cada um deles terá de esperar que a transação do outro termine? Senão, poderá haver conflitos de *login's* iguais?
- **Faz sentido nestes casos usar transações?** Porque se eu tiver a BD preparada para não aceitar valores negativos, no caso dos *stocks* e para que os *login's* sejam únicos já não terei de usar transações, certo?
- **As transações não seriam mais indicadas para da dependências entre tabelas?** Como por exemplo chaves estrangeiras.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Vou te dar uma resposta parcial, pois também não conheço com detalhes o funcionamento de transações (seja no MySQL ou qualquer outro banco):

1. Em primeiro lugar, não se deve confundir [**isolamento**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29) com [***lock***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_%28database%29). O primeiro trata de permitir que duas operações ocorram em paralelo sem que uma interfira na outra (i.e. cada uma enxerga o banco de dados como se estivesse "congelado" no momento em que ela começou até o momento em que ela termina). O segundo trata de evitar problemas no acesso concorrente - em que duas ou mais operações paralelas tentam mexer no mesmo dados (i.e. elas estão "competindo" pelo acesso ao mesmo).

   Uma [**transação**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction) tem dois objetivos distintos: 1) garantir a [**atomicidade**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_%28database_systems%29) da operação - ou ela tem 100% de sucesso, ou é como se ela nunca tivesse começado; a atomicidade garante que, mesmo numa falha "catastrófica" no sistema (ex.: queda de energia) o banco não fique com *parte* da operação feita e parte não. 2) fazer o **isolamento** entre as diferentes operações. Veja a definição de [ACID](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) para mais detalhes.

   Que eu saiba (disclaimer: não sei muito), transações não tem nada a ver com *locks*. Por isso, respondendo ao seu primeiro ponto, o que vai acontecer nessa situação depende mais do modo de *locking* que seu banco usa (lock de leitura, lock de escrita, lock pessimista, lock otimista) do que do uso ou não de transações.

   No seu exemplo do estoque, transações não vão impedir uma eventual [**condição de corrida**](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condi%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_corrida) entre as duas operações: 1) ambas iniciaram, e viram que o estoque era `1`; 2) ambas prosseguiram, sem conhecimento uma da outra (i.e. isoladas); 3) ambas, no final, atribuiram o valor do estoque para `0` (nota: **atribuíram**; não há, em bancos de dados relacionais, a noção de "decrementaram"). O fato do valor ter sido atribuído pra zero **duas vezes** do ponto de vista do banco não é "anormal": afinal, "o valor era pra ser zero, não? dois processos distintos atribuíram ele pra zero..."
2. Respondendo ao seu segundo ponto, de fato não faz sentido num sistema com dezenas de utilizadores simultâneos fazer com que um espere o outro antes de poder fazer *qualquer* operação (lock pessimista). Você vai ter que encontrar outra forma de evitar condições de corrida (as demais respostas dão alternativas à primeira vista viáveis, mas não tenho conhecimento suficiente para avaliá-las de forma confiável).
3. Se faz sentido ou não usar transações, isso é algo que você precisa definir baseado nos princípios ACID: é ruim se "meia transação" for completada? (ex.: a operação "marcar item para envio ao cliente" completou com sucesso, mas a operação "o cliente pagou" falhou) É ruim se uma transação ler dados que ainda não estão no banco de fato? (ex.: cliente A começou a comprar, estoque foi pra zero, cliente B tentou comprar mas viu que o estoque já era zero, cliente A cancelou a compra e o estoque já não é mais zero). Etc.
4. [**Integridade referencial**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity) não tem nada a ver com transações: o banco se encarregará de que toda chave estrangeira aponte para um registro correto, com ou sem transações. Da mesma forma, [**restrições**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_constraints#Constraints) tipo `UNIQUE` etc serão honradas mesmo na presença de acessos concorrentes.

   Inclusive, essa propriedade nos dá mais uma maneira de lidar com possíveis condições de corrida: num sistema que desenvolvi, havia de se controlar o saldo em uma conta bancária; é possível, a princípio, que dois usuários mexessem nesse saldo ao mesmo tempo, de modo que o resultado pudesse ficar incorreto (ex.: o saldo é `1000`; usuário A deposita `500` ao mesmo tempo que usuário B retira `200`; pelo isolamento, um não sabe do outro; não importa qual dos dois "tenha a palavra final", o resultado ficaria incorreto - `1500` no caso do A, `800` no caso do B). Isso é um problema *mesmo* após ter usado uma [solução semelhante à do J.A.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15125/215) (separar transações isoladas da conciliação bancária - onde essas transações são confirmadas de fato).

   A solução foi criar uma "cadeia de saldos": o "saldo atual" de uma conta é uma linha da tabela; ele possui conta, valor, data, e **referência para o saldo anterior** (uma chave estrangeira para a própria tabela). Ao se atribuir um novo saldo (criar mais uma linha), se coloca como "anterior" o último saldo registrado daquela conta. Se duas transações começarem ao mesmo tempo, uma delas vai completar com sucesso, mas a seguinte falhará: pois ao tentar atribuir o saldo anterior, a restrição `UNIQUE` impedirá - pois dois saldos tentaram usar o mesmo valor na coluna `anterior`. Dessa forma, a segunda transação teria que começar de novo - daí já pegando o valor atualizado do saldo.

   Uma estratégia semelhante poderia ser usada para impedir que dois clientes pegassem o último produto do estoque. Nesse caso, aquele que completasse a transação primeiro "venceria", e os demais não teriam sua compra concluída com sucesso. Todos poderiam iniciar uma transação paralelamente, e o cancelamento de um não afetaria os demais - já que só uma transação *concluída* teria qualquer efeito na conclusão das demais. Não estou dizendo que é a melhor maneira (repito: sou inexperiente em BD), mas até onde meu conhecimento alcança é uma maneira correta.

Answer (score 1):

Sim o outro consegue ter acesso ao BD, o que tem de ser feito antes de você remover o produto de estoque você tem de fazer uma verificação se ainda existe quantidade disponível do produto x no estoque logo antes de realizar a operação de remover o produto x do estoque e se possível realizar uma nova consulta de verificação se a quantidade não ficou menor que 0, caso tenha ficado terá de realizar um rollback daquela transaction e exibir alguma mensagem de erro para usuário, pois foram feitas duas operações de compra do mesmo produto ao mesmo tempo com frações de segundos diferentes, é algo difícil de acontecer, mas se pode acontecer tem de ser tratado.

Mas porque de fazer a segunda verificação?
Pois se a quantidade ficar inferior a 0 é porque alguem comprou praticamente junto, mas algum foi nem que seja 1 ms foi antes, então tem de fazer uma verificação antes e depois de remover o produto de estoque.

Mas isso não acarretaria muito acesso ao banco e prejudicaria o servidor?
Para você ter um ecommerce com tanto acesso você irá precisar de um servidor bastante robusto, então não será isso que tem de dar um problema, pois um ecommerce que possuir milhões ou milhares de pessoas comprando ao mesmo tempo ele gera muito dinheiro, logo investimento em servidor e segurança é obrigação.

Comment: Mas e se tiverem os dois (ou dois milhões de utilizadores) a comprar ao mesmo tempo e clicarem na mesma altura em comprar?

Comment: Para isso serve a consulta após a transação, pois se a quantidade ficar inferior a 0 é porque alguem comprou praticamente junto, mas algum foi nem que seja 1 ms foi antes, então tem de fazer uma verificação antes e depois de remover o produto de estoque.

Comment: Isso não vai acarretar muitos acessos a BD e, por consequência, o meu site não ficara muito lento se for utilizado por milhares de pessoas?

Comment: Para você ter um ecommerce com tanto acesso você irá precisar de um servidor bastante robusto, então não será isso que tem de dar um problema, pois um ecommerce que possuir 2 milhões de pessoas comprando ao mesmo tempo ele possui muita gera muito dinheiro, logo investimento em servidor e segurança é obrigação.

Comment: Conseguiu entender? Posso ajudar em mais algo?

Comment: Mas então o facto de ser transação não importa, poderia fazer isso sem a transação, certo?

Comment: Não, pois por exemplo 2 pessoas ao mesmo tempo vai fazer uma operação de comprar o mesmo produto e este produto possui apenas um em estoque, se na segunda verificação o produto estiver com quantidade inferior a 0 então terá de remover o produto do carrinho da pessoa pois ele não está disponível mais em estoque, pois alguém por algumas frações de segundo comprou antes dele, e para realizar o rollback dessa situação terá de usar o transaction, para poder remover o que foi alterado no banco do instante que iniciou a transaction até o erro de estoque indisponivel. Entende?

Comment: Leonardo, por favor, tente consolidar todos seus comentários dentro da resposta. A idéia é que nosso conteúdo deve servir principalmente para visitantes futuros, além de quem fez a pergunta original. Confira o guia [answer].

Answer (score 0):

Penso que o propósito do MySql Transactions não é o de evitar colisões numa BD mas sim o de garantir que uma operação é concluída (mas posso estar equivocado).

No entanto, para evitar colisões ... no modelo habitual cada utilizador é quem activa directamente a execução  das operações dobre a BD ... neste caso, a decrementação de um qualquer valor da tabela de stock ... a incrementação no carrinho de compras, etc ... e claro se dois clicam ao mesmo tempo pode haver o azar das operações colidirem ...

O modelo que sigo para evitar colisões consiste em criar uma tabela onde ficam registadas as intenções dos utilizadores ... e apenas a intenção ... se dois milhões clicam ao mesmo tempo, a única operação realizada sobre a BD é inserção da compra na tabela de intenções ... após isso um trigger (este sim activado pelo utilizador) executa as instruções uma a uma da tabela de intenções por ordem de entrada.

Se milhões quiserem  o mesmo item, o primeiro compra e todos os outros recebem mensagem que já não podem.