# Para que serve um "self join"?

Tags: banco-de-dados, relacionamento

Gostaria de um exemplo para eu entender do por que de eu usar um auto relacionamento em uma mesma tabela?

Tenho conhecimento intermediário em SQL porém ainda não entendo Self Join.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Um uso do self join que eu considero "prático" (uma vez que seu uso para representar árvores pode ser problemático) é para fazer controle de concorrência. Como detalhei em [uma outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15294/215), suponha que você tenha um dado que poderia ser alvo de várias escritas simultâneas, mas é importante que somente uma delas tenha sucesso (exemplo: a compra do último item do estoque). Transações somente não vão impedir uma condição de corrida (i.e. uma sobrescreve os dados da outra), e lock pessimista pode degradar a performance.

Uma solução então é usar uma "cadeia de estoque": representa-se o estoque atual por uma linha na tabela, e quando o estoque muda em vez de mudar a linha cria-se uma nova - com referência para a linha anterior:

```
create table estoque(
    id         integer   not null,
    valor      integer   not null,
    anterior   integer   null        unique,
    primary key (id),
    foreign key (anterior) references estoque(id)
);
```

Dessa forma, pode-se fazer transações paralelas à vontade, pois se der o azar de duas tentarem alterar o estoque ao mesmo tempo, a segunda sempre falhará - pois a nova linha acrescentada violará a restrição `UNIQUE`.

E onde entra o self join? Na hora de buscar qual é o estoque atual:

```
select e1.id, e1.valor
from estoque e1
  left outer join estoque e2 on e2.anterior = e1.id
where e2.id is null;
```

i.e. "selecione a linha que não é a anterior de nenhuma outra linha".

---

**Atualização:** [a resposta do Caffé](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42130/banco-de-dados-controle-de-transa%C3%A7%C3%B5es) numa pergunta relacionada mostra um meio melhor de se controlar a concorrência. Entretanto, ainda há casos em que essa "cadeia de registros" possa ser útil - por exemplo, quando se quer guardar não só o registro mais recente mas também o histórico de valores passados (ao mesmo tempo que se controla a concorrência). Um exemplo seria um conteúdo do tipo *wiki*, em que duas ou mais pessoas podem tentar fazer uma edição ao mesmo tempo. Uma cadeia de revisões não só garante que a edição de uma não sobrescreva a da outra, como também mantém todas as edições no histórico.

Comment: Uma técnica simples para garantir integridade é atualizar primeiro a tabela de saldo, então o registro ficará bloqueado e a transação concorrente apenas esperará em vez de o usuário obter um erro. Eu sugeri isso nesta resposta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42130/banco-de-dados-controle-de-transa%C3%A7%C3%B5es

Answer (score 8):

Árvores podem ser representadas numa única tabela. Por exemplo:

```
eletrônicos
    áudio e vídeo
        TVs
            HD
            Full HD
            4k
        Home Theaters
        ...
    informática
    ...
...
```

Em forma de tabela:

```
id       parent_id     nome
----------------------------------------
1        NULL          eletrônicos
2        1             áudio e vídeo
3        2             TVs
4        3             HD
5        3             Full HD
6        3             4k
7        2             Home Theaters
8        1             informática
```

Uma query que parta de um nó qualquer da árvore pode usar *self joins* para subir na hierarquia:

```sql
SELECT
    categorias.nome AS categoria,
    pai.nome AS pai,
    avo.nome AS avo
FROM categorias
    LEFT OUTER JOIN categorias pai
    ON pai.id = categorias.parent_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN categorias avo
    ON avo.id = pai.parent_id
WHERE categorias.id = 6 -- 4k
```

Resultado:

```
categoria   pai    avo
---------------------------------
4k          TVs    áudio e vídeo
```

Como eu disse no início, árvores *podem* ser representadas nessa estrutura, mas a melhor representação pode ser outra dependendo de como você precisa usar os dados. Para mais detalhes sobre estruturas de árvore em bancos de dados, veja [Como modelar uma estrutura de dados em árvore usando um banco de dados relacional?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2425/como-modelar-uma-estrutura-de-dados-em-%C3%A1rvore-usando-um-banco-de-dados-relaciona)

Answer (score 1):

Self Join é usado quando uma tabela faz referências aos seus próprios dados.
Parecido com isso:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table t1, Table t2
WHERE t1.Id = t2.ID
```