# Performáticamente falando, é bom usar Self Join?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados

Referente a essa pergunta: [Para que serve um "self join"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23029/6026), tecnicamente falando é performático fazer isso, ou usar 1N, 2N e 3N (formas normais) é a melhor maneira?

Só lembrando que nunca afirmei que um quebra regra do outro, é, puramente sobre performática entre os dois.

Comment: Pelo menos nas vezes que usei (comum em contabilidade, quando uma conta referencia sua conta-mãe) funcionou muito bem tanto em SQL quanto naquelas malditas 4GLs que eram moda nos anos 80/90. Self-join sempre foi considerado uma solução elegante.

Answer (score 5):

Não creio haver diferença em performance entre fazer uma junção de uma tabela com outra, ou de uma tabela com ela mesma. Não tenho dados para embasar essa resposta, exceto a ausência de evidência em contrário (poderia fazer benchmarks para comprovar isso - em diferentes SGBDs - mas do ponto de vista lógico é a mesma coisa um ou outro).

(minto: há a possibilidade delas serem até *mais eficientes* que joins externos - uma vez que há apenas um conjunto de meta-dados, índices e dados em si para se armazenar na memória durante uma query. Mas isso é especulação, somente benchmarks poderiam comprovar isso de fato.)

Se você se refere a implementar uma estrutura de árvore usando self join, não é uma boa ideia, mas não pela questão da performance - e sim porque isso complica demais certas queries (em particular se a árvore for profunda). Mas as queries que você conseguir fazer, devem ser tão eficientes quanto queries com joins a outras tabelas.

Mas outros usos devem ser ok. Acabei de acrescentar [uma nova resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/23168/215) à pergunta linkada, dando um outro exemplo de uso prático do self join (no caso, um left outer join). Infelizmente não posso falar muito sobre a performance dele, pois embora eu tenha implementado isso em um sistema real, este nunca teve um volume grande de dados ou de acessos, de modo que não sei qual será sua performance quando/se atingir larga escala.

P.S. A propósito, não há nada nos self joins que viole em si as formas normais. Você pode muito bem ter um modelo normalizado com referências de uma tabela pra si mesma.

Comment: É, também estranhei a questão sobre as formas normais, não via por que um self-join não pudesse/devesse ser considerado normalização. E sobre as árvores, é extremamente comum modelar árvores numa só tabela. É o que mais vejo por aí. Em muitos casos, busca-se um nível de cada vez, então performance não é um problema. Porém, se a intenção é listar todos os nós acompanhados de sua hierarquia completa, realmente a coisa complica. Como eu disse lá no outro post, a melhor estrutura depende da finalidade. E às vezes a solução pode ser combinar mais de uma estrutura.

Comment: Possa ser que não tenha explicado mas eu não afirmei que um quebra a outra eu quis dizer performaticamente, qual é melhor! Uma vez entrei numa empresa e era tudo assim self join sistema era lento demais

Comment: @bfavaretto Concordo, tanto que disse "...as queries que você conseguir fazer, devem ser tão eficientes quanto...". Tenho pouca experiência prática, em particular envolvendo código de terceiros. Mas não duvido que isso seja usado com sucesso em sistemas reais - às vezes os "puristas" teóricos exageram um pouco nas preocupações...

Comment: @HarryPotter Aí eu não sei opinar, pois pra mim uma coisa não tem nada a ver com a outra... (i.e. estaríamos comparando maçãs com laranjas) O que eu posso dizer é que por vezes a normalização **piora** a performance - uma das razões válidas para se desnormalizar um modelo é quando o desempenho está ruim. Mas se o sistema com o qual você trabalhou estava desnormalizado **e** lento, então ele devia ter outros problemas mais graves do que simplesmente usar ou não a característica X ou Y.

Comment: Ok @mgibsombr ...