# Referenciar a própria tabela no Mysql é correto?

Tags: mysql, tabela-banco-de-dados, chave-estrangeira

Eu estou trabalhando num sistema onde o programador anterior estruturou uma determinada tabela de posts referenciando a ela mesma (para poder identificar que seria o comentário do post)

Mais ou menos assim:

```
Posts
-- id
-- post_id => Referencia de Post (ela mesma)
-- texto
-- usuario_id
```

O que tinha post_id seriam os comentários do post relacionado; e o que não tinha era o post normal.

No caso, eu já sei que essa estrutura está completamente errada, pois deveria ter sido criada uma tabela chamada `comentarios` com chave estrangeira definida em `posts`

Mas, fora desse caso, existem outros casos onde há necessidade de se referenciar a própria tabela com uma chave estrangeira (eu nunca vi isso)?

Comment: Não sei se está completamente errada. **Talvez** não seja a melhor solução para este caso mas é perfeitamente válido. Não se prenda a teorias. Se a tabela de comentários tiver a mesma estrutura desta, por que criar uma tabela diferente com a mesma estrutura? Até pode ser útil para dar mais semântica aos dados mas fora isto, não há muita vantagem.

Comment: Eu pensei que pudesse se tratar de um anti-pattern por o nome "foreign key" traduzido ser "chave estrangeira". Ou seja, não vejo estrangeirismo  nenhum num "autorelacionamento"

Comment: @bigown eu sou totalmente a favor de práticas novas, afinal de onde vieram os padrões existentes?

Comment: @Edi.Gomes atualmente na maior partes dos casos da indústria dos livros, cursos, seminários, consultorias e ferramentas :P

Comment: Relacionada ou duplicata? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23029/para-que-serve-um-self-join

Comment: @bfavaretto Relacionada hein, aqui ele não sabia que se tratava de um auto-relacionamento e certamente é uma dúvida sobre modelagem de dados, na outra pergunta o usuário quer saber sobre um comando de utilização do mesmo.

Comment: Um é uma pergunta de se está errado ou não; e o outro é busca de compreensão sobre como fazer o tal do "self join"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não só é correto, mas também é uma mão na roda (eu uso muito e conheço muita gente que usa), isso se chama **Autorelacionamento**, veja:

> Na Álgebra relacional um autorrelacionamento acontece quando os
>   elementos de uma entidade se relacionam com eles mesmos.
>
> A implementação de um autorrelacionamento através de um SQL, é
>   feita da seguinte forma (considere que a tabela FUNCIONARIO é
>   pré-existente e o EMPREGADO foi promovido a GERENTE):

```
ALTER TABLE FUNCIONARIO add constraint EMPR_EMPR_FK foreign key
(GERENTE) references FUNCIONARIO (EMPREGADO);
```

> Note que a constraint
>   EMPR_EMPR_FK relaciona a coluna GERENTE como uma chave estrangeira
>   (Foreign Key) da coluna EMPREGADO na tabela FUNCIONARIO

http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autorrelacionamento

Comment: Pesa o fato do MySql não ter estrutura como o "CONNECT BY" do Oracle ou o "Recursive CTE" do SqlSever , fora isto como já foi dito perfeitamente normal um auto-relacionamento.

Comment: Ops! eu tinha feito um comentário infeliz, mas agora entendi perfeitamente seu exemplo.

Comment: @Motta se tratando do MySQL realmente fica complicado, seria muito bom contar com CONNECT BY, CUBE, CROSS JOIN, OUTER JOIN etc... mas as vezes é a única alternativa para um projeto de baixo custo.

Comment: @Edi.Gomes Postgres não é viável? Não tem custos e conta com mais recursos que o MySQL.

Comment: @Edi.Gomes, já vi alternativas para busca recursiva no Mysql , de fato questão de custo-benefício.

Comment: @Motta realmente, onde eu digo **única** leia-se **ótima**, mas sem contar que no caso do **php** muita gente acaba se **amarrando** ao MySQL.

Comment: @gmsantos vide comentário acima.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que isso é perfeitamente normal. Mas, em outros casos não seria viável como por exemplo:
se eu quiser implementar um comentário do comentário do post eu ficaria sem referência necessitando de outra tabela.