# Erro na base de dados PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estou criando uma página que salva valores no banco de dados MySql usando PDO e não está gravando os dados. Estou usando o seguinte código:

```
<?php
  $conexao = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbTeste', 'root', '');

  $query = "INSERT INTO names(nome, email) VALUES('Wade', 'mercwithamouth@hue.com')";

  $stmt = $conexao->prepare($query);
  $stmt->execute();
?>
```

Porém não salva os dados no banco.

Comment: coloca um espaço depois de `names` (...) e outro depois de `VALUES` (...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema é o nome da sua tabela `NAMES` é uma palavra reservada do mysql, nessa caso é obrigatório escapar o nome com crase ````

Mude:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO names(nome, email) VALUES('Wade', 'mercwithamouth@hue.com')";
```

Para:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `names`(nome, email) VALUES('Wade','mercwithamouth@hue.com')";
                      ^-----^
```

[Lista de palavras reservadas](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/keywords.html)

Comment: Esse nome __names__ coloquei como exemplo, na verdade está __users__, tirando isto, o resto está igual. E testei com outro nome de tabela também, e dá o mesmo problema.

Comment: Quando vc copia e executa a consulta direto no banco qual erro retorna?

Comment: Quando executo direto no phpMyAdmin ele cria a linha normalmente, mas quando tento pela página PHP ele não cria. Fiz uma página para mostrar as linhas existentes e faz normalmente, porém para inserir, não faz.

Comment: O autocommit do banco está ativado? @rogue_psycho

Comment: eu não sei o que isso significa, vou dar uma olhada.

Comment: @rogue_psycho, depois do `execute()`, adicione essa linha e veja se grava, `$conexao->commit();`

Comment: Pronto, resolvi, quando coloquei este comando começou a funcionar. Obrigado!

Comment: @rogue_psycho, o autocommit está desligado então, sobre commit/rollback e transações veja essas perguntas: [Para que serve uma MySQL Transaction?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1924/91) e 
[MySQL Transaction Quando? Como? Porque?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14774/91)