# Gravar dados em duas tabelas apartir de um formulario PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

**Conexão com o bd**

```
$host = "localhost";

$user = "root";

$pass = "";

$conexao = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die (mysql_error());

mysqli_select_db($conexao, "teste2");
```

**HTML**

```
<head>  
    <title>Gravar</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form type="text" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="nome">
        <input type="submit" value="enviar">
</body>
```

**PHP**

```
$nome = $_POST['nome'];

$sql = mysqli_query($conexao,"INSERT INTO teste1 (nome) values ('$nome')");

$sql2 = mysqli_query($conexao, "INSERT INTO teste2 (nome) values ('$nome')");

echo 'Gravado com sucesso';
```

Porque não consigo gravar o (nome) na tabela teste1 e teste2?

Obs: db chama teste2 mesmo

Comment: Ele para de mostrar o erro quando eu gravo qualquer valor no banco de dados, é como se o `$nome = $_POST['nome'];` quando abro está vazia, tanto que grava no banco vazio

Comment: Atualiza o form da sua pergunta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Utilize *prepared statements* para evitar SQL injection. Sua pergunta é um bom exemplo de como usar transações e *exceptions*.

Se a primeiro *insert* funcionar, será gravado no banco de dados. Caso o segundo falhe, a mensagem `Gravado com sucesso` será exibida, além de causar confusão, o banco de dados ficará com um resultado inconsistente.

Use transações para informar ao banco que todos as instruções SQL devem ser realizadas com sucesso para gravar no banco, caso uma falhe as demais será desfeitas (`rollback`).

Ao transformar os erros em *exceptions* com [mysqli_report](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-report.php) qualquer falha em [mysqli_prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) ou [mysqli_stmt_execute](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php) o bloco `catch` será executado, nesse caso vai apenas exibir a mensagem de erro, mas outros tratamentos podem ser feitos.

Caso os dois *inserts* sejam executados com sucesso, [mysqli_commit](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.commit.php), vai colocar em vigor as alterações ou gravar os novos registros.

```
<?php
$conexao = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass);

mysqli_autocommit($conexao, false);
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR|MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

$nome = 'teste';
$insert1 = false;
$insert2 = false;

try{
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conexao, "INSERT INTO teste1 values (?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $nome);
    $insert1 =  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conexao, "INSERT INTO teste2 (nome) values (?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $nome);
    $insert2 = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e){
   echo 'SQLState: '. $e->getCode() .' <br>Descrição: '. $e->getMessage();  
}

if($insert1 && $insert2){
    mysqli_commit($conexao);
    echo 'sucesso';
}

mysqli_close($conexao);
```

**Leitura recomendada:**

[MySQL Transaction Quando? Como? Porque?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14774/91)

[Para que serve uma MySQL Transaction?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1924/91)

Answer (score 1):

Coloque: name="submit", no botao enviar.

E susbstitua o código php pelo de baixo.

```
if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && $_POST['submit'] == 'enviar' ){

    $nome = $_POST['nome'];

    $sql = mysqli_query($conexao,"INSERT INTO teste1 (nome) values ('$nome')");

    $sql2 = mysqli_query($conexao, "INSERT INTO teste2 (nome) values ('$nome')");

    echo 'Gravado com sucesso';

}
```