# Mysqli multi_query INSERT + insert_id multiplas tabelas autoincrement + Foreign key

Tags: php, mysqli

Possuo 2 tabelas por exemplo uma tabela "usuarios" contendo uma `primary key ID` usuário e outra tabela "detalhes" com uma `foreign key do usuario.ID`

A minha necessidade seria de através do php fazer por exemplo em uma única query o *INSERT* do usuário e os seus detalhes. Atualmente eu consegui fazer isso da seguinte forma:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO usuario (usuario.nome,usuario.cpf) VALUES ('$nome','$cpf')";
$trans1 = $mysqli->query($sql);

$sql = "INSERT INTO detalhes (usuario.user_id,detalhes.civil,detalhes.idade) VALUES ($mysqli->insert_id,'$civil','$idade')";
$trans2 = $mysqli->query($sql);

if ($trans1 AND $trans2 == 1){
     echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Usuário Cadastrado');document.location.href=\"index.php?pagina=home\"</script>";
  } else {
     echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Não foi possível inserir o usuario.');document.location.href=\"index.php?pagina=home\"</script>";
  }

$conn->close();
```

Não sei se esta forma está correta, mas foi a que eu consegui por enquanto.

Passei horas tentando obter o mesmo resultado através do multi_query() mas não estou conseguindo de jeito nenhum.

Alguém tem alguma luz?

Valeu!

Comment: Dá pra fazer um pouco diferente usando transações.

Answer (score 0):

Para obter resultados consistentes utilize transações, isso garante que somente será gravado os dados se ambos os insert funcionarem.

Caso o segundo insert falhe automaticamente o primeiro será cancelado(`rollback`). Para mais detalhes [veja](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/89884/91)

```
$driver = new mysqli_driver();
$driver->report_mode = MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR|MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT;

$mysqli->autocommit(false);
try{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO usuario (usuario.nome,usuario.cpf) VALUES (?,?)";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $nome, $cpf);
    $insert1 = $stmt->execute();
    $id = $mysqli->insert_id;

    $sql = "INSERT INTO detalhes (usuario.user_id,detalhes.civil,detalhes.idade) VALUES (?,?,?')";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('isi', $id, $civil, $idade);
    $insert2 = $stmt->execute();

    $mysqli->commit();
}catch(mysqli_sql_exception $e){
    echo 'SQLState: '. $e->getCode() .' <br>Descrição: '. $e->getMessage();
}

if(isset($insert1, $insert2)){
    echo 'sucesso';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Um exemplo que você pode traduzir para o seu projeto:*

**Diagrama das duas tabelas (product e items)**

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Código Fonte**

*Código 1: (Indicaria esse código)*

```
<?php

    $con = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'senha', 'dbase');

    $con->begin_transaction();

    try 
    {

        $sts = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO product(description) VALUES(?)");

        $description = "Café";
        $sts->bind_param('s', $description);    
        $sts->execute();
        $sts->close();

        $productid = $con->insert_id;
        $count = 100;

        $sts = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO items(productid, count) VALUES(?,?)");
        $sts->bind_param('ss', $productid, $count);
        $sts->execute();
        $sts->close();

        $con->commit();

    } 
    catch (Exception $ex) 
    {
        $con->rollback();
    }
```

*Código 2:*

```
<?php

    $con = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'senha', 'dbase');

    $con->begin_transaction();

    try 
    {
        $description = "Feijão";
        $query1 = "INSERT INTO product(description) VALUES('".$description."');";

        $count = 200;
        $query2 = "INSERT INTO items(productid, count) VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),".$count.");";

        $con->multi_query($query1.$query2);

        do {
            $con->store_result();            
        }
        while($con->next_result()); 

        $con->commit();

    } 
    catch (Exception $ex) 
    {
        $con->rollback();        
    }
```