# Problema inserção Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um formulário de **Agendamento** e um de **Cadastro de Funcionário**, um **script** para inserir dados no banco na tabela de **Agendamento** e outro script para o **Cadastro**. No **Agendamento** eu preciso resgatar o **código** do Funcionário que está fazendo o agendamento.

A minha dúvida é de como eu resgato o valor da chave primaria da tabela funcionário e ponho na inserção na tabela agendamento. Levando em conta que já passei as chaves estrangeiras.

```
<?php
        require_once "conexao01.php";

        function filtrarDados($dado) {
            $dado = trim($dado);
            $dado = stripslashes($dado);
            $dado = htmlspecialchars($dado);

            return $dado;
        }


        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

            $connecting = conectaAoMySql();

            $especialdade = $medico = $data = $horario = $nome = $telefone = "";

            $nome =             filtrarDados($_POST["NomePaciente"]);
            $telefone =         filtrarDados($_POST["TelPaciente"]);
            $especialdade =     filtrarDados($_POST["especialidades"]);
            $medico =           filtrarDados($_POST["medico"]);
            $data =             $_POST["dataConsu"];
            $horario =          $_POST["horaConsult"];

            // Tentativa de resgatar o codFuncionario
            $sql = "
                SELECT codFuncionario FROM tblFuncionario WHERE EspecialidadeMedica=$especialdade
            ";
                //Recebe o que o $sql resgato
               $resultado = $connecting->query($sql);

            try {
                //Inicio da transação
                $connecting->begin_transaction();

                $connecting->autocommit(FALSE);

                // Inserção de Dados
                $dados=$connecting->query(" insert into tblpaciente (codPaciente, Nome, Telefone) values (null, '$nome', $telefone)");

                $dados2=$connecting->query(" insert into agenda (codAgendamento, Especialidade, Medico, DataConsulta, Horario, codId, codFuncionario) values (null, '$especialdade', '$medico', '$data', '$horario', LAST_INSERT_ID(), '$resultado')");

                $connecting->commit();
                echo "Executado com Sucesso!";
                $connecting->close();
            }

            catch (Expection $e) {
                    $connecting->rollback();

                    echo "Ocorreu um erro na transação: " . $e->getMessage();
            }
        }

    ?>
```

-

```
try
    {

        $conn->begin_transaction();

        $conn->autocommit(FALSE);

        $dados=$conn->query("insert into tblfuncionario (codFuncionario, NomeFuncionario, DataNascimento, Sexo, EstadoCivil, Cargo, EspecialidadeMedica, CPF, RG, Outro)
            values (null, '$nomeFunc', '$dataNasc', '$sexoFunc', '$estadoCivil', '$cargo', '$especialidade', '$cpf', '$rg', '$outro')");

        $dados2=$conn->query("insert into enderecofuncionario (CEP, Logradouro, Numero, Complemento, Bairro, Cidade, Tipo, UF, codId)
        values ('$cep', '$logradouro', '$numero', '$complemento', '$bairro', '$cidade', '$tipo', '$uf', LAST_INSERT_ID())");

        $conn->commit();

        echo "Transacao efetuada com sucesso";
        $conn->close();
    }

    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        $conn->rollback();

        echo "Erro na transacao: ". $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Se o funcionário que está cadastrando está logado no sistema, é só você pegar os dados de sessão dele, COOKIE ou SESSION, dependendo do modo com que você fez ele autenticar.

Comment: Coloque seu script de inserção para que possamos auxilia-lo.

Comment: @W.Faustino, mas se o funcionário for um médico as vezes ele não pode estar logado, mas na tabela Agendamento, tem que estar o código do médico que fará consulta.

Comment: Mas o valor do médico vai na coluna 'Medico' e o do funcionário vai na coluna 'codFuncionario', este último deve sempre estar logado, vc alimenta do ID da sessão, e o valor de 'Medico' vc alimenta do valor preenchido no formulário.

Comment: Medico Faustino codMedico (mesma coisa codFuncionario) = 1
so quero q o 1 apareça na tabela de Agendamento para referenciar, acredito eu que não precise estar logado para o mesmo, já no form o campo select vai ter o nome do medico ex; Faustino e automaticamente na tabela agendamento aparecer o código do medico ao invés do nome.

Comment: Não tenho certeza se `LAST_INSERT_ID()` vai funcionar como vc deseja. Da uma olha [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/91251/91) em especial no `$id = $mysqli->insert_id;`

Comment: @rray a questão está que eles sao de scripts diferente. Uma maneira q imaginei que daria certo, seria fazendo um select porém n está dando.