# PHP - Fazer 3 INSERT em tabelas diferentes com relacionamento entre elas

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Gostaria do aval de vocês.
Preciso fazer **3** `INSERT` de uma única vez.
Só que eu preciso tambem pegar o ultimo ID de cada tabela, para fazer o **relacionamento** das tabelas.

Esta correto, fazer dessa forma?

```
if($_GET['operacao'] == 'addPrimeiroCadastro'){
    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO grupo (id_condominio, nome) VALUES ('".$loginUltimoRegistro."','".$_GET['inputPriGrupo']."')");
    $ultimoGrupo = $mysqli->insert_id;

    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO unidades (id_condominio, id_grupo, nome) VALUES ('".$loginUltimoRegistro."','".$_GET['inputPriGrupo']."')");
    $ultimoUnidade = $mysqli->insert_id;

    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO morador (id_condominio, id_unidade, funcao, nome, cpf, senha) VALUES ('".$loginUltimoRegistro."', '".$ultimoUnidade."', ,'sin', '".$_GET['inputPriNome']."', '".$_GET['inputPriCPF']."', '".$_GET['inputPriSenha']."')");   
}
```

Comment: [Gravar dados em duas tabelas apartir de um formulario PHP](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/89884/91)

Comment: Funciona mais o fato de você não testar se inseriu corretamente é um problema.
Pode ser que o INSERT não funcione podendo não pegar o $mysqli->insert_id correto. Se não inserir o $mysqli->insert_id pode ser de uma inserção de dados anterior pois vc está utilizando uma conexão global.

Answer (score 2):

Use transações em duas fases para garantir que sejam feitos os três inserts(grupo, unidades e morador) ou nenhum em caso de falha.

```
if($_GET['operacao'] == 'addPrimeiroCadastro'){

    mysqli_autocommit($conexao, false);
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR|MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

    try {
        $mysqli->begin_transaction();

        $sql = "INSERT INTO grupo (id_condominio, nome) VALUES (?,?)";
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param('is', $loginUltimoRegistro, $_GET['inputPriGrupo']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $ultimoGrupo = $mysqli->insert_id;

        $sql = "INSERT INTO unidades (id_condominio, id_grupo, nome) VALUES (?,?,?)";
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
        $nome = "Doge";
        $stmt->bind_param('iis', $loginUltimoRegistro, $_GET['inputPriGrupo'], $nome);
        $stmt->execute();
        $ultimoUnidade = $mypresqli->insert_id;

        $sql = "INSERT INTO morador (id_condominio, id_unidade, funcao, nome, cpf, senha) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
        $funcao = "sin";
        $stmt->bind_param('iissss', $loginUltimoRegistro, $ultimoUnidade, $funcao, $_GET['inputPriNome'], $_GET['inputPriCPF'], $_GET['inputPriSenha']);
        $stmt->execute();

        $mysqli->commit();
    }catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e){
        echo 'erro ao inserir, código: '. $e->getCode() .' mensagem: '. $e->getMessage();
        $mysqli->rollback();
    }
}
```

Comment: Tem que desligar autocommit no php não?

Comment: @DiegoFelipe não entendi a pergunta.

Comment: `mysqli_autocommit($conexao, false);` Você já tinha desligado, desatenção minha :(

Comment: @DiegoFelipe, sem problema :)