# Duvida com php e mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Alguem ai poderia me ajudar a tirar uma duvida aqui? Estou começando no php agora, criei um banco de dados no mysql(phpmyadimin) e relacionei a chave primaria de uma tabela como chave estrangeira em outra. Na hora que executo o script php com a ideia de salvar no banco de dados nao salva, mas se eu tirar o relacionamento entre as tabelas, salva. O que pode é isso?

Segue o código

```
$sql = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO usuario(nome) VALUES('$nome')");
$sql = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO imc(peso,altura,imc) VALUES('$peso','$altura','$imc')");
```

Abaixo estrutura das tabelas.

```
`Estrutura da tabela `imc`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `imc` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `peso` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `altura` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `imc` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `id_usuario` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id_usuario` (`id_usuario`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

Estrutura da tabela `usuario`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `usuario` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

--
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `usuario`
--

INSERT INTO `usuario` (`id`, `nome`) VALUES
(1, 'shs'),
(2, 'sem nome'),
(3, 'ertt');

--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Limitadores para a tabela `imc`
--
ALTER TABLE `imc`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `relacionamento` FOREIGN KEY (`id_usuario`) REFERENCES `usuario` (`id`);
```

Comment: Qual campo primario de qual tabela é chave estrangeira, e em qual outra tabela? Explique melhor, não está claro o problema.

Comment: a tabela é assim: usuario que tem id como primaria e nome; e a segunda tabela é imc que tem id chave primaria, peso, altura, imc, e id_usuario como chave estrangeira.

Comment: Por que você não está informando o id do usuário na query? E você não informou exatamente que erro que ocorre. Clique em [edit] e adicione mais informações na pergunta.

Comment: ele é auto incremento acho que nao é necessario nao !

Comment: id_usuario esta relacionado com id na tabela usuario

Comment: Se id_usuario é chave estrangeira na tabela imc, por quê você não está inserindo na query da tabela imc? Talvez seja este o motivo do erro. Adicione como estão as duas tabelas na pergunta.

Comment: vou colocar aqui e testar

Comment: e passo oque de parametro pra ele na query ? deixo vazio ?

Comment: Samuel, adicione o schema das tabelas na pergunta clicando em [edit], sem saber como está os campos das duas tabelas fica dificil ajudar.

Comment: Não vejo motivo para separar essa informação em duas tabelas, a menos seja apenas para estudo. Veja essa resposta => http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/89884/91

Comment: Sim é so para estudos sim !
usando o incremento $last_id = mysqli_insert_id(); funcionou como havia dito estou começando no php, a minha missao agr é selecionar um usuario em um formulario<option> e exibir em outra tela os dados do mesmo !

Answer (score 1):

Is ID dos foreign keys sao relacoes, nao sao uma introducao de dados automatica para que a relacao se mantenha. 
Voce é que tem que manter a integridade da relacao quando faz introducao dos dados.

Voce tem que primeiro obter o ID do usuario quando guarda dados na tabela de usuario, e depois usar esse ID para guardar os dados na tabela imc.

Exemplo:

```
$sql = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO usuario(nome) VALUES('$nome')");
$last_id = mysqli_insert_id();
$sql = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO imc(usuario_id, peso,altura,imc) VALUES($last_id, '$peso','$altura','$imc')");
```