# MySQL Transactions escrita na mesma tabela

Tags: mysql, transações

Ao ver [esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1932/7210) resposta fiquei com esta dúvida:

Se tivermos 2 transações a ser tratadas ao mesmo tempo, na primeira (A) estamos a escrever na tabela x, na segunda (B) se tentarmos escrever na tabela x ao mesmo tempo, o que acontece?

Sendo que "escrever" poderá ser **atualização**, **inserção** ou **remoção**:

- (A) remove registo y, (B) atualiza registo y;
- (A) insere novo registo, (B) insere novo registo;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dependendo do caso a segunda transação irá ficar bloqueada até que a primeira acabe.

Algumas *engines* do MySQL como o [InnoDB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/internal-locking.html) suportam travamento por registro (*row-level locking*), enquanto em outras o travamento é por página ou pela tabela toda.

Então, em um banco bem configurado, duas transações podem escrever na mesma tabela sem haver bloqueios na execução, desde que não estejam alterando o mesmo registro.

Especificamente sobre a resposta citada, ela trata bastante sobre os níveis de isolamento, isto é, como uma transação `B` **vê** os dados que são alterados por uma transação paralela `A`. Dependendo da configuração, a transação `B` pode ver os dados ainda não efetivados (comitados) pela transação `A`. Em outra configuração, a transação `B` vê os dados originais, como se `A` não existisse.

Enfim, não vou detalhar a resposta novamente, mas é essa a ideia.

Sobre a questão de **INSERTS simultânetos**, se a tabela usa auto incremento, [conforme a documentação](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html), isso gera um lock exclusivo até o final da transação. No entanto, ao usar chaves geradas por alguma outra fonte não vai ter problemas de concorrência.

Se a engine é InnoDB e o nível de isolamento é `READ LOCAL`, [conforme a documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html), é possível fazer inserts simultâneos.

Para tabelas MyISAM há um parâmetro chamado [`concurrent_inserts`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_concurrent_insert) para definir quantas transações serão permitidas inserir ao mesmo tempo.

No caso da remoção (`DELETE`) ou atualização (`UPDATE`), em geral novas transações que tentarem executar as ações serão bloqueadas quando houver uma transação em andamento possuindo o "direito" sobre os registros em questão (*lock*).

Comment: E se forem duas inserções simultâneas?

Comment: @JorgeB. Vou acrescentar uma atualização na resposta.