# Usando last_insert_id(), sera que e' credivel caso varios usuarios insiram ao mesmo tempo no banco de dados?

Tags: mysql, sql, procedure

Tenho uma duvida em relacao ao metodo `last_insert_id()` do mysql.
E o seguinte: Estou a criar um procedimento para inserir em 3 tabelas, exemplo:

> pessoa (idPessoa,nome,apelido)
>
> empregado(idEmpregado,idPessoa,cargo)
>
> contacto(idContacto,idPessoa,celular)

Entao, o meu procedimento insere dados nessas duas tabelas e eu estou usando o `last_insert_id()` para recuperar o `idPessoa` da tabela Pessoa, para usar nas duas tabelas empregado e contacto.

```
CREATE DEFINER=user`@`localhost PROCEDURE inserirPessoa (var_nome
 varchar(45), var_apelido varchar(45), var_cargo varchar(45), var_celular bigint)

BEGIN

    INSERT INTO pessoa (nome, apelido) values (var_nome, var_apelido);
    
   
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() into @idPessoa;


    INSERT INTO candidato (idPessoa, Cargo) values (@idPessoa, var_Cargo);


    INSERT INTO contacto (idPessoa, celular) values (@idPessoa, var_celular);

END
```

O código Funciona direitinho. A minha duvida é, pensando no pior dos casos, se mais de um user submeter o cadastro desses dados, sera que o `idPessoa` nao estará vulnerável a ser recuperado pelo Empregado errado???
Como Funciona esse `last_insert_id()`?

Comment: Isso aí vai depender do tipo de isolamento da transação, [MySQL Transactions escrita na mesma tabela](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14894/91)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O manual do MySQL deixa claro que o [LAST_INSERT_ID](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) é por conexão, assim, é perfeitamente seguro usá-lo da maneira que você está usando independente de qualquer configuração de isolamento de transação.

Comment: Obrigada, Sergio Garcia, vou procurar ler o manual do MySQL...Valeu