# Como resgatar ID do último registro gravado com MySQLi

Tags: php, mysqli

Não estou conseguindo resgatar o ID do último registro inserido em meu BD, está vindo como Zero, a inclusão está funcionando e no momento de fazer um update o script falha.

Já tentei com `mysql_insert_id()` e `mysqli_insert_id()`

O que fiz foi isso:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO WFDocContratacao ( Unidade, Cargo, NumeroVagas, MotivoContratacao, Departamento, TipoVaga, HorarioTrabalho, Jornada, DataAdmissao, ContratoExperiencia, SalarioContratual, Codigo1, SalarioPosExperiencia, Codigo2, Atividade, Aproveitamento, NomeIndicado, Escolaridade, CNH, ConhecimentoTI, EstadoCivil, Idade, Sexo, Experiencia,          TempoExperiencia, Caracteristicas, OutrosRequisitos) VALUES   (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

// Preparar os dados: s = string / i = inteiro / d = decimal / b = blob
if($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql) ){

    $stmt->bind_param(
        "ssssssssssdsdssssssssssssss",
        $_POST["UnidadeRequisitante"],
        $_POST["Cargo"],        
        $_POST["NumeroVagas"],
        $_POST["Motivo"],
        $_POST["Departamento"],
        $_POST["TipoVaga"],
        $_POST["HorarioTrabalho"],
        $_POST["Jornada"],
        // Definir como STRING na lista acima
        $Data,
        $_POST["ContratoExperiencia"],      
        $fSalarioContrato,
        $_POST["Codigo1"],
        $fSalarioPosExperiencia,
        $_POST["Codigo2"],      
        $_POST["Atividade"],
        $_POST["AproveitamentoInterno"],
        $_POST["NomeFuncionarioIndicado"],
        $_POST["Escolaridade"],
        $_POST["CNH"],
        $_POST["Informatica"],
        $_POST["EstadoCivil"],
        $_POST["Idade"],
        $_POST["Sexo"],
        $_POST["Experiencia"],
        $_POST["TempoExperiencia"],
        $_POST["Caracteristicas"],  
        $_POST["OutrosRequisitos"]  
    );  

    $IdDoctoCont =  mysql_insert_id();

   //executando a query
    if($stmt->execute()){   
        $aretorno["msg"] = "Registro inserido com sucesso.";
        // $stmt->close();
    }else{
        $aretorno["msg"] = "Ocorreu um erro na inclusão dos dados: " . $stmt->error . ". Verifique.";
        $aretorno["status"] = "ERRO";
    }   

    $sqlUp = "UPDATE WFTarefa SET IdDoctoCont = ? WHERE IdTarefa = ?";

    // Preparar os dados: s = string / i = inteiro / d = decimal / b = blob
    if($stmt = $conn->prepare($sqlUp) ){

        $stmt->bind_param(
            "ii",
            $IdTarefa,
            $IdDoctoCont
        );
    }           

}else{
    $aretorno["msg"] = "Ocorreu um erro na preparação dos dados: "  . $stmt->error . ". Verifique.";
    $aretorno["status"] = "ERRO";
}

//close the database
$conn->close();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No seu código faltou um `i`,a chamada de `insert_id` deve ser feita **após** o `execute().` também garanta que o update só será realizado se o insert realmente ocorrer com sucesso caso contrario exibe a mensagem de erro, use uma transação em duas fases isso pode ser feito diretamente pelo banco ou pelo driver de conexão.

Com o mysqli existe duas formas de fazer, a primeira disponível desde o php5 é desligar o auto commit com o método/função [auto_commit()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.autocommit.php) antes de executar o primeiro comando sql em caso de sucesso chamar [commit()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.commit.php) para gravar de forma 'permanente' o resultado, o [rollback()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.rollback.php) acontece quando a instrução retorna erro também pode ser chamado arbitrariamente.

A outra forma é a chamar [begin_transaction()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.begin-transaction.php) no lugar de `auto_commit()` porém só está disponível a partir da versão 5.5

Evite misturar os estilos procedural e OO do mysqli.

Mude:

```
$IdDoctoCont =  mysql_insert_id();
if($stmt->execute()){
```

Para:

```
$conn->autocommit(false);

if($stmt->execute()){ //Caso o insert tenha sucesso, pega o id inserido e faz o update
    $aretorno["msg"] = "Registro inserido com sucesso.";
    $IdDoctoCont =  $conn->insert_id;

    $sqlUp = "UPDATE WFTarefa SET IdDoctoCont = ? WHERE IdTarefa = ?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sqlUp);
    $stmt->bind_param("ii", $IdTarefa, $IdDoctoCont);

    if($stmt->execute()){
       $conn->commit(); //salva todas as operações realizados no banco.
    }

}else{
    $aretorno["msg"] = "Ocorreu um erro na inclusão dos dados:". $stmt->error ." Verifique";
    $aretorno["status"] = "ERRO";
}
```

Leitura recomendada:

[Para que serve uma MySQL Transaction?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1924/91)

[Mysql - comandos de transação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html)

[Manual - insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)

Comment: Olá @rray, obrigado pela dica, agora consigo obter o valor do último ID mas não consigo efetuar o Update.

Comment: @adventistapr, no seu código $idTarefa não parece definada. Chame novamente $stmt->execute();

Comment: Obrigado @rray pela excelente dica e ajuda, os links recomendados foram extramente úteis.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode testar isto também: **lastInsertId()** http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Answer (score 1):

O comando `mysqli_insert_id` pode te ajudar nisso.
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php