# Como trabalhar com if e else?

Tags: php, if, else

Bom dia.

Gostaria de Obter ajuda de vocês para montar esse código pois não estou conseguindo implementa-lo.

```
$query1 = "INSERT INTO paciente VALUES ('NULL, $nome_paciente, $nome_doutor')";

$id_paciente = mysql_insert_id();

$query2 = "INSERT INTO servico VALUES ('NULL, tipo_servico, data_servico,{$id_paciente})";

$id_servico = mysql_insert_id();

$query3 = "INSERT INTO estagio VALUES ('NULL, {$id_servico}, data_estagio, tipo_estagio')";
```

No seguinte padrão:

```
if (@mysql_query(INSERT INTO cad_paciente VALUES (NULL, $nome_paciente, $nome_doutor))) {

if(mysql_affected_rows() == 1){
    echo "Registro efetuado com sucesso<br />";
}

}
```

Nesse padrão acima consigo inserir apenas um registro numa tabela como faço para continuar a inserção.

Comment: Não ficou clara sua dúvida

Comment: Como montar essa query com as 3 opções no formato dessa de baixo verificando se foi salvo

Comment: O jeito mais simples seria usar algum driver(MySQLi ou PDO) com suporte a transações, ai vc gravar as 3 modifições com sucesso ou abortar o processo na primeira falha. Em outra palavras ou grava tudo ou não grava nada.

Comment: Por exemplo se o insert de `servico` falhar, o insert de `pacientes` é revertido ou fica gravado?

Comment: [Como resgatar ID do último registro gravado com MySQLi](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/63705/91) e [Gravar dados em duas tabelas apartir de um formulario PHP](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/89841/91)

Comment: Isso ai revert nao salva nada e tenta novamente

Comment: Se você não sabe trabalhar com if e else, deve estar na hora de estudar mais a fundo programação, entenda isso como uma crítica construtiva.

Comment: @PauloHenriqueNeryOliveira suas edições não estão apresentando melhorias na pergunta, está até adicionando coisas irrelevantes, por isso foi rejeitada.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Pelo o que eu entendi você deve informar o que quer inserir onde .. Uma boa dica para ficar bem claro e organizado é usando a função `sprintf()` do PHP.

Tenta mais ou menos assim:

```
<?php

$q = mysql_query(
    sprintf(
        "INSERT INTO cad_paciente (id, nome, doutor) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s')",
        "NULL",
        $nome_paciente,
        $nome_doutor
    )
);

if($q) {
    echo "Registro efetuado com sucesso<br />";
}
```

Neste exemplo, a função **sprintf()** está recebendo uma string que recebe 3 chaves, que são os **%s** dentro do código. Ele pega estas chaves dentro da primeira string e substitui pelos parâmetros subsequentes que são passados na função.

Espero que seja esta a sua dúvida e que eu a tenha respondido .. Abs.

## UPDATE

É vivendo e aprendendo, rsrs
Baseado na sua dúvida e usando [este post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1924/para-que-serve-uma-mysql-transaction) como referência eu consegui entender e executar o bloco de inserção de uma única vez com o [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli).
Segue o código que acho que resolverá seu problema e sanará sua dúvida ..

```
<?php

// cria conexão com o banco de dados usando o classe mysqli orientado a objetos
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test");

$deuCerto = true;

// começa a transação
$conn->query("START TRANSACTION");

if($deuCerto) {
    $query1 = $conn->query("INSERT INTO paciente VALUES (NULL, '".$nome_paciente."', '".$nome_doutor."')");
    $id_paciente = $query1->insert_id;
    // se falhar, para o restante do código
    if(!$query1) {
        $deuCerto = false;
    }
}

// se na insert anterior não tiver sucesso, não executa mais
if($deuCerto) {
    $query2 = $conn->query("INSERT INTO servico VALUES (NULL, '".$tipo_servico."', '".$data_servico."', ".$id_paciente.")");
    $id_servico = $query2->insert_id;
    if(!$query2) {
        $deuCerto = false;
    }
}

// se na insert anterior não tiver sucesso, não executa mais
if($deuCerto) {
    $query3 = "INSERT INTO estagio VALUES (NULL, '".$id_servico."', '".$data_estagio."', '".$tipo_estagio."')";
    $id_estagio = $query3->insert_id;
    if(!$query3) {
        $deuCerto = false;
    }
}

// se nenhuma das inserções derem erro, irá inserir tudo de uma vez
if($deuCerto) {
    $conn->query("COMMIT");
} else { // se houver algum erro, desfaz todos as alterações
    $conn->query("ROLLBACK");
}
```

Comment: minha duvida e como continuar a inserção dos dadosnas outras tabelas

Comment: Isso mesmo, obrigado pela orientação, agora so irei pesquisar para entender as funções usadas aqui mas e isso mesmo que eu queria. muito obrigado

Comment: Então marca como resposta, rsrs