# Chave estrangeira - Inserir ID da tabela 1 na Tabela 2 PHP/MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Boa Tarde, sou iniciante em programação e estou com a seguinte dificuldade. Tenho 2 tabelas :

```
CREATE TABLE produto(
  id_produto int(10)  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY auto_increment,
  nome varchar(45) NOT NULL,
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

e a segunda tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE img_produto(
  id_img INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  id_produto int(10)  NOT NULL,
  nome_img VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  FOREING KEY (id_produto) REFERENCES produto (id_produto) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Minha dúvida é como proceder para que ao cadastrar um produto com a respectiva imagem, o ID do produto(id_produto) da tabela `produto` seja inserido automaticamente na tabela `img_produto` no campo `id_produto` ?

Comment: Você precisa pegar o id(atual) do produto inserido e gravar na tabela imagem, mais detalhes em: [Como resgatar ID do último registro gravado com MySQLi](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/63715/91) ou [essa outra](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/89884/91)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se eu entendi bem o que o [@Guilhermenascimento disse](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30827761#30827761), você pode usar o [LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) para recuperar esse valor. Ficaria algo como isso:

```
INSERT INTO produto(nome) VALUES ('Produto1'); 

INSERT INTO img_produto(id_produto, nome_img) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),'Nome da Imagem');
```

Pelo manual do PHP possui o [mysqli_insert_id()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php), que obtém o id da inserção anterior, como o exemplo do próprio site:

```
<?php
    $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password', 'mydb');
    if (!$link) {
        echo 'Debugging errno: ', mysqli_connect_errno(), PHP_EOL;
        echo 'Debugging error: ', mysqli_connect_error(), PHP_EOL;
        exit;
    }
    
    if (mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO mytable (product) values ('kossu')")) {
        printf("Last inserted record has id %d\n", mysql_insert_id());
    }
```

Porém, essa forma possui algumas notas que devem ser observadas, para não ocasionar erros. Tais notas podem ser vistas [na documentação oficial do PHP.](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)

#### Edição

Conforme alertado nos comentários pelo [@rray](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/138939/chave-estrangeira-inserir-id-da-tabela-1-na-tabela-2-php-mysql/138941?noredirect=1#comment287984_138941), não use funções que comecem com `mysql_`, pois se trata da API antiga que foi descontinuada no **PHP 5.5.0** e removida no **PHP 7.0.0**, como pode ser visto [ma documentação oficial em inglês.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

Como alternativa, segundo o manual, você tem o [mysqli_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) e o [PDO::lastInsertId](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php).

Comment: Não use a documentação em português, olhe (a diferença) o mesmo link em inglês http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php O.o'

Comment: @rray Obrigado pelo aviso. Sabia que a documentação em português era criticada, mas não sabia que tinha esse tipo de problema.

Answer (score 0):

Tudo depende de como sua aplicação vai funcionar.
Se o cadastro de imagem for feito separadamente você vai precisar de um campo com o id do produto.
Você pode usar um `<input type="hidden" name"id_produto" value"ID DO PRODUTO AQUI">`.
Ou você pode fazer usar um campo select com os produtos listados:

```
<select>
   <option value="id do produto aqui">produto 01</option>
   <option value="id do produto aqui">produto 02</option>
   <option value="id do produto aqui">produto 03</option>
</select>
```

Caso a inserção de produto e imagem seja feita no mesmo form você vai precisar inserir o produto e pegar o id para usar na tabela imagem.
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert_lastid.asp

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Amigo, vlw pela ideia, mas não sei se isso vai funcionar de forma dinâmica...