# Armazenar novo Valor, atualizando Valor Antigo

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Alguém pode me ajudar com uma função em PHP e MYSQL?

Hoje tenho um view para Lançamento de Despesa e Receita.
Tambem tenho um caixa, que, quando lanço uma Receita,o valor é somado ao caixa e quando lanço uma despesa, o valor é subtraído deste caixa. (até aqui funciona)

Estou tendo problemas ao editar o valor deste lançamento.

Quando estou editando uma despesa por exemplo, está somando o total do caixa com o valor da despesa.

Quero que o valor do caixa seja atualizado quando editar um lançamento.

Tipo: Como se eu excluísse o lançamento antigo e incluísse um novo lançamento com o mesmo ID, mas valor diferente e o caixa atualizasse de acordo com a edição.

Tenho uma tabela que contem uma coluna "valor" e outra Coluna "valor_antigo".

Preciso que o valor_antigo armazene sempre o ultimo valor.

> Cénario:
>   **Primeiro Cadastro:**
>
>   Valor = 10,00
>   Valor Antigo = Null
>
> **Primeira Alteração:**
>
>   Valor = 30,00
>   Valor Antigo = 10,00
>
> **Segunda Alteração:**
>
>   Valor = 50,00
>   Valor Antigo = 30,00

E preciso que a função faça o mesmo, hoje estou utilizando a seguinte função para atualizar o saldo:(Não funciona de acordo)

```
function atualizaSaldoEditar($valor,$conta,$tipoLancamento) {

    $valor = $this->input->post('valor');
    $valorAntigo = $this->input->post('valor_antigo');
    $conta = $this->input->post('conta_id');        

    $atual = "SELECT saldo from contas where idConta=?";
    $this->db->query($atual , array($conta));
    $receita = $atual - $valorAntigo + $valor;
    $despesa = $atual - $valorAntigo + $valor;
    $tipoLancamento = $this->input->post('categoria_id');

    if($tipoLancamento == 1){
        $sql = "UPDATE contas set saldo = saldo + ? WHERE idConta = ?";
        $this->db->query($sql, array($receita , $conta));
    }
    else{
        $sql = "UPDATE contas set saldo = saldo - ? WHERE idConta = ?";
        $this->db->query($sql, array($despesa , $conta));
    };        
}
```

Tabela Contas(onde está armazenado o saldo)

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `contas`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `contas` (
  `idConta` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `conta` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `banco` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `numero` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,  
  `saldo` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `status` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `data_cadastro` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idConta`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;
```

Tabela onde são armazenados os lançamentos

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `lancamentos`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `lancamentos` (
  `idLancamentos` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `descricao` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `valor` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  `valor_antigo` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  `data_vencimento` DATE NOT NULL,
  `categoria_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `conta_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `data_pagamento` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `baixado` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `cliente_fornecedor` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `forma_pgto` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `tipo` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `anexo` VARCHAR(250) NULL,
  `clientes_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idLancamentos`),
  INDEX `fk_lancamentos_clientes1` (`clientes_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_lancamentos_clientes1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`clientes_id`)
    REFERENCES `clientes` (`idClientes`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;
```

Comment: `UPDATE contas set valor_antigo = valor, valor = ? WHERE idConta = ?` Não seria só isso na SQL?

Comment: Na tabela contas, não existe uma coluna valor_antigo

Comment: O que está acontecendo, não entendi o problema.

Comment: Então, coloque as informações existentes em tabelas, código, etc etc etc, você colocou isso para gente !!!

Comment: Coloquei agora.

Comment: Qual a duvida??? porque a SQL que eu postei de exemplo seria uma grande referencia.

Comment: *valor* e *valor_antigo* não teria que ser um `decimal`? Tem problemas!

Comment: Não estou tendo problemas quando ser decimal, quero armazenas somente o valor já calculado, mas posso alterar isso.

Comment: @WagnerFilho altere, enquanto a tempo. o código em PHP é simples praticamente você já o fez precisa então alterar a SQL para adequar!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, este é o problema.
Já tentei outras querys, mas não consegui.
Sinceramente, não sei fazer.
Até porque a atualização de valores na tabela, não esta funcionando e não encontrei uma forma de fazer funcionar.

Comment: Trabalhar com contas é sempre complicado. Pode ser uma boa trabalhar com estornos, ao invés de querer editar um lançamento. Ou seja, ao "editar" o lançamento, antes de realizar a operação, você carrega o lançamento do banco, marca ele como estornado e adiciona/subtrai o saldo (dependendo se for crédito ou débito). Então você faz um novo lançamento com o valor atual e atualiza novamente o saldo. Pode parecer burocrático, mas ficará mais fácil rastrear alterações e correções caso seja necessário, principalmente quando envolve dinheiro.

Comment: @NewtonWagner, sim, com toda certeza!
E olhando por este lado, fica mais seguro.

Vou tentar algo deste tipo...

Já estou alterando o layout.

Answer (score 0):

No seu código, você não faz menção nenhuma à tabela lançamentos, ou seja, não está registrando os lançamentos que vão resultar no saldo da tabela contas.

Além da atualização do saldo na tabela contas, você precisa executar um `INSERT INTO...` na tabela de lançamentos. Isso deve estar sendo feito em outro método que não foi colado aqui (algo tipo *inserirLançamento*).

Pela sua pergunta, parece que você está querendo salvar também o último saldo antes do lançamento atual. Para isso, deve-se acrescentar a coluna *valor_antigo* na coluna contas (em vez da tabela lançamentos). Aí sim com um `UPDATE` você resolve (conforme @VirgilioNovic). Se a coluna valor_antigo na tabela já serve para registrar isso, é só você procurar onde esta tablea está sendo usada para registrar os lançamentos e usar o um update na tabela "lancamentos".

Comment: Não estou tendo problema para incluir os valores. Existe um método que está fazendo isso.

Estou tendo problema para incluir o valor atualizado mantendo o valor antigo(Atualizando a cada edição) e estou tendo problema para atualizar este valor na query update, na tabela contas.

Comment: O jeito vai ser criar uma nova coluna `saldo_anterior` na tabela `contas` para isso.
E no final do método `function atualizaSaldoEditar($valor,$conta,$tipoLancamento)` executar o `UPDATE` (@VirgilioNovic): `UPDATE contas set saldo_anterior = saldo, saldo = ? WHERE idConta = ?`

Atenção, pois na tabela contas não há nenhuma coluna *valor*!

Comment: Isso, verdade na tabla contas, contém a coluna Saldo(que recebe o calculo do valor do lançamento).

Eu criei uma coluna saldo_anterior da tabela contas.

Mas de qualquer forma, acredito que deveria existir uma função para lançar sempre o valor antigo e o valor atual

Comment: Isso depende da modelagem, não entendi qual seria a função de ter o valor do lançamento anterior. Cada lançamento é algo único (tem data, tipo, valor únicos). Ter somente o valor como o registro do "anterior" acho algo "incompleto". Se você quer mesmo ter o valor do lançamento anterior, sugiro criar um campo "id_lancamento_anterior" onde você pode armazenar somente o ID do lançamento anterior. Gerenciar isso pode ser complicado (por exemplo, no caso de apagar um lançamento). Mas é uma ideia para ter o registro imediatamente anterior.

Comment: Para se ter o histórico, um select agrupando pelas colunas mais importantes (categoria_id, conta_id) retorna o histórico e resolve bem a necessidade.

Comment: Na verdade, o lançamento anterior, era só uma forma que encontrei para poder editar um lançamento, subtrair pelo lançamento anterior do ID e adicionar o lançamento novo para o mesmo ID.

Answer (score 0):

Recomendo que deixe o trabalho com o MySQL, usando [TRIGGERS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html)

Dessa forma poderá fazer algo do tipo:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `nome_trigger` 
BEFORE UPDATE ON `tabela` 
FOR EACH ROW SET 
SaldoAnterior = OLD.Saldo
```

Suponha uma tabela:

```
- id (Padrao : AUTO INCREMENT)
- Saldo
- SaldoAnterior (Padrão : "0")
```

Se fizer isto:

```
INSERT INTO tabela (`Saldo`)  VALUES ('10')
```

Supondo que este INSERT seja de ID = 1, fazendo isto:

```
UPDATE tabela SET Saldo = 50 WHERE id = 1;
```

Automaticamente irá acionar o `TRIGGER`, tendo como resultado:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE id = 1

id: 1
Saldo: 50
SaldoAnterior: 10
```

Isso é um exemplo de uma outra (e na minha opinião melhor) solução, você deve adequar as suas necessidades, logicamente.

*Não irei enfatizar isto, porém cuidado ao manipular "saldo" fora de [`TRANSACTION`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1924/para-que-serve-uma-mysql-transaction) e sem `LOCK` e esteja atento em qual nível de isolamento está usando, como não há todo o código acredito que esteja tudo ok.*

Answer (score -3):

Para atualizar o valor do caixa ao editar um lançamento, você precisa armazenar o valor antigo antes de fazer a atualização. Você já está armazenando o valor antigo na coluna "valor_antigo" da tabela "lancamentos", o que é um bom começo.

Em relação à função atualizaSaldoEditar(), você está obtendo o valor atual da conta com a consulta SQL, mas não está armazenando o resultado em uma variável. Isso pode ser feito usando o método row() do CodeIgniter. Além disso, você está subtraindo o valor antigo e adicionando o novo valor ao saldo atual, mas isso não é correto. O correto é subtrair o valor antigo e adicionar o novo valor à diferença, para obter o novo saldo.

Aqui está uma versão modificada da função atualizaSaldoEditar() que deve fazer o que você precisa:

```php
function atualizaSaldoEditar($valor, $conta, $tipoLancamento) {
    $valor = $this->input->post('valor');
    $valorAntigo = $this->input->post('valor_antigo');
    $conta = $this->input->post('conta_id');
    $tipoLancamento = $this->input->post('categoria_id');

    $conta_atual = $this->db->query("SELECT saldo FROM contas WHERE idConta=?", array($conta))->row()->saldo;
    $diferenca = $valor - $valorAntigo;
    
    $novo_saldo = ($tipoLancamento == 1)
        ? $conta_atual + $diferenca
        : $conta_atual - $diferenca;

    $this->db->query("UPDATE contas SET saldo=? WHERE idConta=?", array($novo_saldo, $conta));
}
```

Nesta versão da função, estamos obtendo o valor atual da conta e armazenando-o na variável $conta_atual. Em seguida, calculamos a diferença entre o novo valor e o valor antigo e adicionamos essa diferença ao valor atual para obter o novo saldo, que é armazenado na variável $novo_saldo. Em seguida, atualizamos o valor do saldo na tabela "contas" com a consulta SQL.