# O que são as transações Begin, Commit e Rollback?

Tags: sql, sql-server

O que são as Transações Begin, Commit e Rollback? E como usá-los?

Exemplo na prática vai ajudar bastante no entendimento.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Na verdade transação é o processo todo de consulta ou manipulação do banco de dados. É uma forma de estabelecer que algo deva ser feito [atomicamente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=atomicidade), ou seja, ou faz tudo ou faz nada, não pode fazer pela metade. É tudo feito em uma viagem da aplicação para o banco de dados. Em condições normais enquanto a transação não termina outras transações não podem ver o que esta está fazendo. [Entenda o que é o ACID](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/203857/101).

Esses 3 comandos SQL são para controlar isso.

O [`BEGIN TRANSACTION`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/begin-transaction-transact-sql?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) indica onde ela deve começar, então os comando SQL a seguir estarão dentro desta transação.

O [`COMMIT TRANSACTION`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/commit-transaction-transact-sql?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) indica o fim normal da transação, o que tiver de comando depois já não fará parte desta transação. Neste momento tudo o que foi manipulado passa fazer parte do banco de dados normalmente e operações diversas passam enxergar o que foi feito.

O [`ROLLBACK TRANSACTION`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/rollback-transaction-transact-sql?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) também fecha o bloco da transação e é a indicação que a transação deve ser terminada, mas tudo que tentou ser feito deve ser descartado porque alguma coisa errada aconteceu e ela não pode terminar normalmente. Nada realizado dentro dela será perdurado no banco de dados.

Ao contrário do que muita gente acredita *rollback* no contexto de banco de dados não significa reverter e sim voltar ao estado original. Um processo de reversão seria de complicadíssimo à impossível. Um processo de descarte é simples e pode ser atômico.

A maioria dos comandos SQL são transacionais implicitamente, ou seja, ele por si só já é uma transação. Você só precisa usar esses comandos citados quando precisa usar múltiplos comandos e todos esses devam rodar atomicamente. Ou seja, eles funcionam como as chaves de um código, eles criam um bloco. Na verdade está mais para o `using` do C# já que há uma consequência garantida no final da execução.

```
CREATE TABLE ValueTable (id int);  
BEGIN TRANSACTION;              -- aqui começa a transação
       INSERT INTO ValueTable VALUES(1);  
       INSERT INTO ValueTable VALUES(2);  
COMMIT;                         -- aqui termina e "grava" tudo
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Insert/Transaction.sql).

Enquanto não dá o `COMMIT` essas inserções não constam de fato no banco de dados. Um `ROLLBACK` descartaria tudo feito antes.

A documentação tem mais informações e o assunto é interessante, pena não ter mais perguntas sobre isto.

Apesar de ser MySQL dá para [entender mais sobre transações](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1924/101).

Comment: Eu não sabia que existiam estás transações no MySQL, você acha interessante trocar a tag `Sql-Server`por `independe-de-linguagem`?

Comment: Ou minha pergunta pode ser duplicada @Bigown?

Comment: @Marconi aí é c/ vc, mas ñ acho duplicata, eu só vi depois que tinha algo, mas tem alguma especificidades que é melhor encaminhar para a documentação da Microsoft mesmo.

Comment: Ainda pretendo postar uma resposta minha, pois vou me aprofundar um pouco mais aqui @bigown. Assim que tiver tempo e postar marco sua resposta.

Comment: Ótimo, vou aguardar, eu vou dar uma melhoradinha na minha tb, e acabei de postar outra que vai ajudar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/203857/101

Comment: Aparentemente saíram negativando tudo aqui, gostaria de saber se tem algo errado na minha resposta e se posso melhorar algo.

Comment: A sua resposta está muito clara. Se existir alguém que tenha algum conhecimento extra por favor partilhe.

Answer (score 8):

No livro `Sistemas de banco de dados`, de Elmasri & Navathe, os capítulos 17 a 19 (páginas 395 a 452, 4ª edição) tratam da teoria do processamento de transações. Sobre a pergunta "O que são transações", o texto informa que "*Uma transação inclui uma ou mais operações de acesso ao banco de dados - englobam operações de inserção, exclusão, alteração ou recuperação*" e também cita que "*Uma transação é uma unidade atômica de trabalho que ou estará completa ou não foi realizada*".

Outra parte de sua pergunta menciona `BEGIN TRANSACTION`, `COMMIT` e `ROLLBACK`: "*Um meio para especificar os limites de uma transação é estabelecer explicitamente declarações de início de transação e fim de transação*". No caso das instruções SQL que citou, `BEGIN TRANSACTION` refere-se a início da transação e `COMMIT` ao final da transação.

Ao utilizar o par `BEGIN TRANSACTION`/`COMMIT` definem-se os limites da transação: "*... todas as operações de acesso ao banco de dados, entre as duas, serão consideradas parte da transação*".

Como exemplo, o caso clássico de transferência de valor entre duas contas bancárias. A programação deve ser de tal forma que não seja possível a retirada do valor da conta e, por uma falha qualquer, o processo seja interrompido antes que o valor seja depositado na conta do destinatário.

```
-- código #1
declare @contaDe char(6), @contaPara char(6), @Valor money;

set @contaDe= '029820';
set @contaPara= '407302';
set @Valor= 1200.00;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

UPDATE CONTA_CORRENTE
  set saldoConta= saldoConta - @Valor
  where numConta = @contaDe;

UPDATE CONTA_CORRENTE
  set saldoConta= saldoConta + @Valor
  where numConta = @contaPara;

COMMIT;
go
```

No caso de transferência bancária há vários procedimentos adicionais, mas o objetivo aqui é exemplificar a utilização das instruções `BEGIN TRANSACTION` e `COMMIT`.

Já a instrução `ROLLBACK` "*reverte uma transação explícita ou implícita ao começo da transação ou a um ponto de salvamento dentro da transação*", conforme consta na documentação da instrução. Geralmente é utilizada quando ocorre algo inesperado no processamento e é necessário então desfazer o processamento realizado na transação.

O conceito de transação está intimamente ligado a [concorrência de processos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concorr%C3%AAncia_(ci%C3%AAncia_da_computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)) e também às propriedades [ACID](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) (atomicidade, consistência, isolamento e durabilidade).

Documentação em português, para SQL Server:

- [BEGIN TRANSACTION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms188929.aspx)
- [COMMIT TRANSACTION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms190295.aspx)
- [ROLLBACK TRANSACTION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms181299.aspx)
- [SAVE TRANSACTION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms188378.aspx)

Comment: @Marconi: O livro "Sistemas de banco de dados", de Elmasri & Navathe, é adotado na PUC Minas; é provável que você o tenha utilizado no curso de SI.