# READPAST e NOLOCK O que são?

Tags: sql, sql-server, terminologia

O que é `READPAST` e `NOLOCK`?

Tenho visto bastante o uso de `NOLOCK`, mas o `READPAST` vi o uso agora, praticamente da mesma forma, ou seja.

```
FROM dbo.table t WITH(READPAST)
```

e

```
FROM dbo.table t WITH(NOLOCK)
```

Mas qual a diferença entre eles? E quando devemos usar um ou o outro?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Essas cláusulas são dicas para o otimizador de *queries* atender alguma demanda de forma melhor, em geral só deve ser usado quando é certo que precisa de uma semântica de acesso aos dados diferente do padrão. Pode ter consequências nefastas se não souber o que está fazendo.

- `NOLOCK` - ignora o travamento de linhas que estão sendo atualizadas em outra transação e acesso aos dados mesmo em estado potencialmente inconsistente. Então pode pegar dados inconsistentes.
- `READPAST` - ignora apenas travamentos feitos em páginas, mas não travamentos nas linhas. Tende a pegar dados inconsistentes, mas a chance é menor.

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: como assim travamentos feitos em páginas?

Comment: O travamento pode ser feito linha a linha ou pode travar cada página, que pode conter várias linhas, ou pode conter apenas uma parte de uma linha, são formas diferentes dependendo da granularidade necessária, então esses travamento serão ignorados e o dado é acessado, mas se tiver um travamento específico na linha ele será respeitado. Essas coisas dependem de entendimento profundo do funcionamento do banco de dados, não é só conhecer o isto faz, por isso recomenda-se não usar até ser estritamente necessário.

Answer (score 6):

## [Compare SQL Server NOLOCK and READPAST Table Hints](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4468/compare-sql-server-nolock-and-readpast-table-hints/)

## TL;DR

```
CREATE TABLE TESTE ( ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, VALOR CHAR(1) )
INSERT INTO TESTE(ID,VALOR)
VALUES (1,'A'),(2,'B'),(3,'C')
```

## Rode está instrução em uma janela do `SQL`

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION Transaction1
DELETE FROM TESTE
WHERE ID=1

UPDATE TESTE
SET VALOR= 'D' 
WHERE VALOR='C'

INSERT INTO TESTE(ID, VALOR)
VALUES(4,'E'),(5,'F') GO WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'
ROLLBACK
```

## Em outra janela rode também

```
SELECT * FROM TESTE WITH (NOLOCK)
```

*O resultado será*:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Após completar a primeira transação, rode o select novamente veja que o resultado mudou.*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Conseguiu perceber a diferença?

Ao usar a dica do `NOLOCK` não só é possível ler dados modificados mas também ler dados incorretos, que são resultado das mudanças na localização física dos dados feitas por outras transações. (*Como mostrado no exemplo acima*)

## Mudando para `READPAST`

```
SELECT * FROM TESTE (READPAST)
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso ocorre porque esta é a única linha que não foi modificada por **Transaction1**

## CONCLUSÃO

`NOLOCK` permite leitura de linhas sujas (*linhas que estão sendo usadas por outras transações*) e podem causar problemas de consistência durante operações de *`Table/Index Scan`*. `NOLOCK` pode melhorar bastante a performasse([*`Como usar SELECT WITH NOLOCK para melhorar a Performance?`*](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/fcatae/2010/10/05/como-usar-select-with-nolock-para-melhorar-a-performance/)), porém tome cuidado com isso, veja os [*`Efeitos colaterais do WITH (NOLOCK) – Parte I`*](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/fcatae/2010/04/28/efeitos-colaterais-do-with-nolock-parte-i/)

`READPAST` ler linhas que não estão sendo usadas por outras transações.

Recomendo a leitura:

- <sub>[O que são as transações Begin, Commit e Rollback?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/203669/o-que-s%C3%A3o-as-transa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-begin-commit-e-rollback)</sub>
- <sub>[O que é deadlock no SQL Server?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/64484/o-que-%C3%A9-deadlock-no-sql-server/64490)</sub>

Comment: Estou sem tempo no momento, mas prometo que irei ajustar essa resposta.

Comment: Legal, vou esperar para ver o ajuste, a principio deu para entende com os exemplos, mas ainda ache que esta faltando alguma cousa para entender melhor.

Comment: Sua query esta com um erro no GO ... INSERT INTO TestTable(ID, Value)