# Como criar Serviço Atômico?

Tags: característica-linguagem

**Descrição de Atômico**

> As **operações ficam em memória** e só **são persistidas todas de uma vez**. Se **uma operação falhar**, **todas as operações são revertidas**.

Abaixo segue um cenário fictício para compor a pergunta...

> No cenário bancário de modo geral para transferência de valores, temos as seguintes regras de negócios:
>
> **a)** Escolher o valor a ser movimentado
>
> **b)** Verificar saldo atual
>
> **c)** Remover o Valor em conta da Origem
>
> **d)** Adicionar o Valor recebido na conta do destinatário

Sabemos que por lógica e além de se tratar de algo bancário onde leva uma enorme segurança quanto a isto, todas estas etapas (funções) só devem afetar o valor, caso todas estejam persistidas e concluídas com sucesso, por exemplo: Caso o usuário esteja na etapa `c)` e a internet do usuário cair e não for atômico, o valor do saldo seria manipulado e geraria problemas.

**Pergunta**

> Sabendo disto, em relação a lógica do algoritmo, como seria uma aplicação atômica em relação ao algoritmo? Dando um exemplo em um cenário Frontend desacoplado do Backend, onde o Frontend faz a comunicação com o Backend através de requisições.
>
> No frontend devo armazenar o "saldo" (o qual não é o que está no `DB`, apenas uma representação visual em uma `tag html`) e fazer as operações e ir armazenando as mesmas em um `localStorage`, `sessionStorage` e a partir de todas ações verificar se a situação foi concluída com sucesso e ai sim mandar a requisição para o banco de dados?

**Nota**

> Eu li sobre o [ACID](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/203857/o-que-%C3%A9-acid-em-banco-de-dados), porém não ficou claro para mim se tiver a situação da pergunta acima.

Comment: O termo já foi respondido em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/253852/101. Não sei se o resto não é amplo. Não sei o que funcional tem a ver com isso, o que começa deixar a pergunta não clara. Inclusive "sabemos bem que essas ações são atômicas" eu não sei, nada indica aí que são, podem e até onde entendo deveriam ser.

Comment: E aí meu amigo @Maniero ? Então eu tinha lido esta questão que você postou, mas o que eles dizem na resposta è algo específico a threads e eu gostaria de saber em geral não específico, sobre a programação funcional, nos dois sabemos o que è.. O que eu quis dizer sobre isto è o seguinte: Cada ação ali seria uma função específica, porém como o código è executado linha a linha de cima para baixo, fica a questão.. ao chegar na letra a) seria executada e salva no banco de dados e assim por diante, normalmente funciona assim correto? Como eu abordo este tema utilizando a descrição de atômico acima?

Comment: É que sem alguma forma de concorrência ser atômico ou não pouco importa em memória. Em banco de dados falamos disto em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/203857/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/203669/10. Pode ser útil: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/101. Eu não sei se nós dois sabemos o que é funcional ,eu sei que eu sei, o que está dizendo indica que não sabe, ou o texto está confuso demais pra eu perceber. Eu acho que tudo isso acaba respondendo o que quer saber, ou não entendi o que quer. Isso pode ser útil se quiser ir mais baixo nível: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192938/101.

Comment: @Maniero em breve irei ler os links e talvez “melhorar” a pergunta.. Bem eu sempre aprendi que programação funcional enfatiza a aplicação de funções e que evita estados ou dados imutáveis. Não sei se expliquei bem, porém eu considerei está parte do conceito com o exemplo acima e quis dizer que o valor em banco è um dado imutável até ser finalizado corretamente as funções, e levei a descrição de atômico em consideração.

Comment: Por isso parece que esse assunto nada tem a ver com o que está falando. Inclusive não tem nada de imutabilidade nisso, aí tem um dúvida clara que você tem.

Comment: @Maniero agora estou digitando do celular, assim que eu chegar em minha residência eu irei melhorar a pergunta com termos técnicos e mais descrições.