# Importação de .txt usando php + mysql

Tags: php, mysql, txt

Boa noite, tenho tentado de outras formas mas não consegui.
Preciso executar a query do código abaixo de uma só vez ao invés de inserir linha por linha no banco de dados.
Alguém teria a salvação?

```
<?php

set_time_limit(0);
if (!isset($seguranca)) {
exit;
}
$arquivo_tmp = $_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'];

//ler todo o arquivo para um array
$dados = file($arquivo_tmp);

//Ler os dados do array
foreach ($dados as $linha) {
//Retirar os espaços em branco no inicio e no final da string
$linha = trim($linha);
//Colocar em um array cada item separado pela virgula na string
$valor = explode(',', $linha);

//Recuperar o valor do array indicando qual posição do array requerido e atribuindo para um variável
$data = $valor[0];
$hora = $valor[1];
$pis = $valor[2];



//Criar a QUERY com PHP para inserir os dados no banco de dados
$result_usuario = "INSERT INTO func_batidas (data, hora, pis) VALUES ('$data', '$hora', '$pis')";
//Executar a QUERY para inserir os registros no banco de dados com MySQLi
$resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conectar, $result_usuario);
}
//Criar a variável global com a mensagem de sucesso
//Redirecionar o usuário com PHP para a página index.php
$_SESSION['msg'] = "<div class='alert alert-success'>Batidas importadas!</div>";
$url_destino = pg . "/listar/list_importa_batidas";
header("Location: $url_destino");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar `transaction`. Caso não saiba o que é isso, recomendo a leitura da pergunta abaixo.

- [Para que serve uma MySQL Transaction?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1924/para-que-serve-uma-mysql-transaction)

Na extensão `mysqli_*`, podemos iniciar uma *transaction* utilizando o método `begin_transaction` ou a função `mysqli_begin_transaction`, por exemplo:

```
/**
 * Orientado à Objeto
 * Inicia a transação apenas para leitura
 */
$conn->begin_transaction(MYSQLI_TRANS_START_READ_ONLY);

/**
 * Procedural
 * Inicia a transação para leitura e escrita
 */
mysqli_begin_transaction($conn, MYSQLI_TRANS_START_READ_WRITE);
```

Após iniciarmos a transação, podemos informar nossas *queries* através da função `mysqli_query` ou do método `query`, por exemplo:

```
/**
 * Orientado à Objeto
 */
$conn->query("INSERT INTO ...");

/**
 * Procedural
 */
mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO...");
```

Feito isso podemos "comitar" nossa transação. Isso significa que tudo o que fizermos após o `begin_transaction`, será executado no banco de dados.

---

Uma alternativa, é a função `mysqli_multi_query` ou o método `multi_query`. Como o próprio nome já diz, aqui nós podemos informar várias *queries* delimitadas por um caractere (geralmente o caractere é o `ponto-e-vírgula`);

Para fazermos isso, basta que salvemos as *queries* em um *array*, por exemplo:

```
$queries = [];

foreach ($dados as $linha) {
    $queries[] = "INSERT INTO func_batidas (data, hora, pis) VALUES ('$data', '$hora', '$pis')";
}
```

> Observe que não adicionamos um delimitador no final, faremos isso no próximo passo.

Agora só precisamos transformar esse *array* em *string* e também adicionar nosso delimitador, para isso podemos utilizar a função `implode`, por exemplo:

```
/**
 * Orientado à Objeto
 */
$conn->multi_query( implode(";", $queries) );

/**
 * Procedural
 */
mysqli_multi_query($link, implode(";", $queries) );
```

Pronto! Dessa forma a extensão do `MySQLI` se encarregará de executar todas as *queries* ao mesmo tempo.