# Método create no laravel com rollback

Tags: laravel-5.4

Estava estudando **laravel 5.4** e me surgiu uma dúvida. Como um bom programador pesquisei no google de diversas formas e não achei nada parecido.

Imagina a seguinte caso:

```
$prod = $this->product->create([
    name -> 'produto 1',
    valor -> '100',
    active -> '0'
]);

if($prod){
    $id = $prod->id;

    $tProd = $this->relTypeProduct->create([
        idProduct -> $id,
        idTypeProduct -> 1
    ]);

    if($tProd){
        $message = 'Produto cadastrado com sucesso!';
        DB::commit();
        return true;
    }else{
        $message = 'Erro ao cadastrar o tipo de produto!';
        DB::rollback();
        return false;
    }
}else{
    $message = 'Erro ao cadastrar o tipo de produto!';
    return false;
}
```

Quero que se der algum erro no segundo **create**, ele dê um `rollback()` para apagar o primeiro **create**.
Mas não está acontecendo isso, ele faz o primeiro **create** a variável `$prod` recebe `true` e se der um erro no segundo **create**, ele não dá o `rollback`.

O `DB:commit()` e o `DB:rollback()` não funciona nesse caso. Alguém teria uma solução para isso?

Comment: É preciso fazer a operação dentro de uma transação para poder usar commits e rollbacks.

Comment: [Para que serve uma MySQL Transaction?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1924/18246)

Comment: O primeiro Create ele cadastra no banco, o problema é que, eu gostaria que desse um rollback se o segundo create der algum erro.

Comment: Você leu meu comentário? Pra fazer isso é preciso usar uma transação.

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi inserindo `DB::beginTransaction();` no começo do meu código.

```
DB::beginTransaction();

$prod = $this->product->create([
    name -> 'produto 1',
    valor -> '100',
    active -> '0'
]);
if($prod){
    $id = $prod->id;

    $tProd = $this->relTypeProduct->create([
        idProduct -> $id,
        idTypeProduct -> 1
    ]);

    if($tProd){
        $message = 'Produto cadastrado com sucesso!';
        DB::commit();
        return true;
    }else{
        $message = 'Erro ao cadastrar o tipo de produto!';
        DB::rollback();
        return false;
    }
}else{
    $message = 'Erro ao cadastrar o tipo de produto!';
    return false;
}
```