# Como garantir o insert de todos os dados MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Preciso garantir que os TODOS os dados sejam inseridos, caso contrario, realizar uma reversão e os que forem inseridos sejam removidos.

Tenho o seguinte caso

```
$dia1_entrada = $_POST['dia1_entrada'];
$dia1_pausa_almoco = $_POST['dia1_pausa_almoco'];
$dia1_inicio_tarde = $_POST['dia1_inicio_tarde'];
$dia1_saida = $_POST['dia1_saida'];
$dia1_carga = $_POST['dia1_carga'];
$data[]=array("fk_id_jornada_trabalho"=>$resultado,"dia"=>1,"entrada"=>$dia1_entrada,"inicio_pausa"=>$dia1_pausa_almoco,"fim_pausa"=>$dia1_inicio_tarde,"saida"=>$dia1_saida,"duracao_em_horas"=>$dia1_carga,"fk_id_administrador"=>ADM_ID);

$dia2_entrada = $_POST['dia2_entrada'];
$dia2_pausa_almoco = $_POST['dia2_pausa_almoco'];
$dia2_inicio_tarde = $_POST['dia2_inicio_tarde'];
$dia2_saida = $_POST['dia2_saida'];
$dia2_carga = $_POST['dia2_carga'];
$data[]=array("fk_id_jornada_trabalho"=>$resultado,"dia"=>2,"entrada"=>$dia2_entrada,"inicio_pausa"=>$dia2_pausa_almoco,"fim_pausa"=>$dia2_inicio_tarde,"saida"=>$dia2_saida,"duracao_em_horas"=>$dia2_carga,"fk_id_administrador"=>ADM_ID);
```

a inserção é feita da seguinte forma

```
foreach($data as $item)
   $jornadaDao->insert($item);
```

Porém, se por algum motivo, ocorrer uma falha de conexão ou outro motivo que ocasione a não inserção de uma linha por exemplo, eu deveria retornar um erro e não inserir nenhuma. Mas, da forma que está, se ocorrer isso, ele vai inserir algumas e não inserir outras. 
Existe alguma forma de fazer com que o insert só seja validado caso todos tenham inseridos, e caso não seja, não inserir nenhum?
A solução pode ser feita em PHP, ou SQL mesmo...

Comment: Relacionado: [Pra que serve uma MYSQL Transaction?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1924/para-que-serve-uma-mysql-transaction/1940#1940)

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar Transaction, isso garante que que todas as transações sejam realizadas,
caso alguma dê erro nada será comitado ou inserido segue exemplo.

```
try{
  $db->beginTransaction();
// sua regra INSERT - DELETE - UPDATE
$db->commit();
}catch() {
  $db->rollBack()
}
```

Exemplo bem simples